# Can I use jQuery with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Is it possible to use jQuery selectors/DOM manipulation on the server-side using Node.js?

Comment: I wonder: Why use on the server-side while you can do it on the client-side?

Comment: Perhaps you might want to create a web scrapper that scraps specific information at regular intervals and stores the results in a database?  This would not be as practical from the client-side.

Comment: You should also take a look at phantomjs, which allow you to emulate a browser server side with V8 engine.

Comment: @deeperx DOM manipulation on the server side could be useful when making a crawler. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31361044/778272).

Comment: YES - have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50231309/814620) - I prefer this over using cheerio, since you get the full power of jQuery selector.

Answer (score 587):

Yes. First, install the dependencies

```bash
npm install jquery jsdom
```

then

```js
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;

var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48561379/3624257).

Comment: Is it possible to use jQuery ajax from node.js with that npm module?

Comment: where should we add that code index.js ?

Comment: @ajsie I was able to do `$.ajax('http://127.0.0.1:8888')` after starting a server on port 8888 with `nc -kl 8888`. Trying to query `$.ajax('http://example.com')` fails with `Error: Cross origin null forbidden`

Comment: @mercury add that code to index.js and the run `node index.js`. Or you can name it any other filename and pass that filename to `node`

Answer (score 59):

Yes you can, using a library I created called [nodeQuery](https://github.com/tblobaum/nodeQuery)

```
var Express = require('express')
    , dnode = require('dnode')
    , nQuery = require('nodeQuery')
    , express = Express.createServer();

var app = function ($) {
    $.on('ready', function () {
        // do some stuff to the dom in real-time
        $('body').append('Hello World');
        $('body').append('<input type="text" />');
        $('input').live('click', function () {
            console.log('input clicked');
            // ...
        });
    });
};

nQuery
    .use(app);

express
    .use(nQuery.middleware)
    .use(Express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
    .listen(3000);

dnode(nQuery.middleware).listen(express);
```

Comment: Note that nodeQuery is actually changing the page of the user in real time, so it's even cooler than one might expect.

Comment: I was searching something like this when I stumbled here... I have just looked at nQuery and jquery node packages and nQuery was updated a year ago where jquery was yesterday... Is nQuery no longer developed? and does jquery affect client side as nQuery does? Has anybody tried them both maybe?

Comment: @Logan nQuery is basically just jquery. the difference is the code is run on the server and, rather than delivering the jquery code to the browser, it runs the code on the server and remotely executes dom manipulation to connected browsers. Also note that nQuery was an experimental project, and while I will accept pull requests to fix bugs, it was never created for any specific purpose or project so it has not had many commits

Comment: @ThomasBlobaum not working for me, error : `, express = Express.createServer();` and `TypeError: Express.createServer is not a function` any idea ?

Comment: @ThomasBlobaum looks like you haven't got the latest version of Express. Try `npm install --save express` in your command prompt.

Answer (score 57):

At the time of writing there also is the maintained [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio).

> Fast, flexible, and lean implementation of core jQuery designed
>   specifically for the server.

Comment: Can Cheerio use deferred events and ajax calls?

Comment: does not support a lot of selectors like `:gt(1)`

Comment: In my experience this one works best. Its a lot faster than JSDOM.

Comment: @Hoffmann, I spent a second to check docs for you. No, it does not. Cheerio has DOM-related methods only.

Answer (score 38):

## A simple crawler using Cheerio

This is my formula to make a simple crawler in Node.js. It is the main reason for wanting to do DOM manipulation on the server side and probably it's the reason why you got here.

First, use [`request`](//github.com/request/request) to download the page to be parsed. When the download is complete, handle it to [`cheerio`](//github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) and begin DOM manipulation just like using jQuery.

Working example:

```js
var
    request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

function parse(url) {
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        var
            $ = cheerio.load(body);

        $('.question-summary .question-hyperlink').each(function () {
            console.info($(this).text());
        });
    })
}

parse('http://stackoverflow.com/');
```

This example will print to the console all top questions showing on SO home page. This is why I love Node.js and its community. It couldn't get easier than that :-)

Install dependencies:

> npm install request cheerio

And run (assuming the script above is in file `crawler.js`):

> node crawler.js

---

### Encoding

Some pages will have non-english content in a certain encoding and you will need to decode it to `UTF-8`. For instance, a page in brazilian portuguese (or any other language of latin origin) will likely be encoded in `ISO-8859-1` (a.k.a. "latin1"). When decoding is needed, I tell `request` not to interpret the content in any way and instead use [`iconv-lite`](//github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) to do the job.

Working example:

```js
var
    request = require('request'),
    iconv = require('iconv-lite'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

var
    PAGE_ENCODING = 'utf-8'; // change to match page encoding

function parse(url) {
    request({
        url: url,
        encoding: null  // do not interpret content yet
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        var
            $ = cheerio.load(iconv.decode(body, PAGE_ENCODING));

        $('.question-summary .question-hyperlink').each(function () {
            console.info($(this).text());
        });
    })
}

parse('http://stackoverflow.com/');
```

Before running, install dependencies:

> npm install request iconv-lite cheerio

And then finally:

> node crawler.js

---

### Following links

The next step would be to follow links. Say you want to list all posters from each top question on SO. You have to first list all top questions (example above) and then enter each link, parsing each question's page to get the list of involved users.

When you start following links, a [callback hell](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/) can begin. To avoid that, you should use some kind of promises, futures or whatever. I always keep [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) in my toolbelt. So, here is a full example of a crawler using async:

```js
var
    url = require('url'),
    request = require('request'),
    async = require('async'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

var
    baseUrl = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';

// Gets a page and returns a callback with a $ object
function getPage(url, parseFn) {
    request({
        url: url
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        parseFn(cheerio.load(body))
    });
}

getPage(baseUrl, function ($) {
    var
        questions;

    // Get list of questions
    questions = $('.question-summary .question-hyperlink').map(function () {
        return {
            title: $(this).text(),
            url: url.resolve(baseUrl, $(this).attr('href'))
        };
    }).get().slice(0, 5); // limit to the top 5 questions

    // For each question
    async.map(questions, function (question, questionDone) {

        getPage(question.url, function ($$) {

            // Get list of users
            question.users = $$('.post-signature .user-details a').map(function () {
                return $$(this).text();
            }).get();

            questionDone(null, question);
        });

    }, function (err, questionsWithPosters) {

        // This function is called by async when all questions have been parsed

        questionsWithPosters.forEach(function (question) {

            // Prints each question along with its user list
            console.info(question.title);
            question.users.forEach(function (user) {
                console.info('\t%s', user);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Before running:

> npm install request async cheerio

Run a test:

> node crawler.js

Sample output:

```
Is it possible to pause a Docker image build?
    conradk
    Thomasleveil
PHP Image Crop Issue
    Elyor
    Houston Molinar
Add two object in rails
    user1670773
    Makoto
    max
Asymmetric encryption discrepancy - Android vs Java
    Cookie Monster
    Wand Maker
Objective-C: Adding 10 seconds to timer in SpriteKit
    Christian K Rider
```

And that's the basic you should know to start making your own crawlers :-)

---

### Libraries used

- [request](//github.com/request/request)
- [iconv-lite](//github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite)
- [cheerio](//github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)
- [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Answer (score 22):

in 2016 things are way easier. install jquery to node.js with your console:

```
npm install jquery
```

bind it to the variable `$` (for example - i am used to it) in your node.js code:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
```

do stuff:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'gimme_json.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    data: { "now" : true }
});
```

also works for gulp as it is based on node.js.

Comment: What version of node are you using?  On Mac, Node 6.10.2, jquery 2.2.4, `var $ = require("jquery"); $.ajax // undefined`  (Downvoted for the moment).

Comment: @AJP and you are sure you did `npm install jquery` first?

Comment: Yes.  `> console.log(require("jquery").toString());` gives me the factory function:
`function ( w ) {
  if ( !w.document ) {
    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
  }
  return factory( w );
}`  I had to use the answer above with jsdom:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4129032/539490

Comment: @AJP ok, that's strange.

Comment: I get exactly the same factory function as @AJP does. What version of jquery did you use, @low_rents?

Answer (score 20):

I believe the answer to this is now yes.
https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

```
var navigator = { userAgent: "node-js" };  
var jQuery = require("./node-jquery").jQueryInit(window, navigator);
```

Comment: I'm sorry to report that it is going to take more work to get jQuery running on jsdom.  Sizzle however does work!  I really want to keep jsdom as light as possible, so adding in full browser emulation like env.js is not really a priority at this time.

Comment: never mind, i found the modified copy that's bundled with jsdom.

Comment: FYI node-jquery is deprecated now in favor of jquery

Comment: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Answer (score 18):

`npm install jquery --save` **#note ALL LOWERCASE**

`npm install jsdom --save`

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html>`);
var $ = require("jquery")(dom.window);


$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/nhambayi',function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: smooth.....................

Answer (score 10):

jQuery module can be installed using:

```
npm install jquery
```

Example:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'jquery.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/'
};

var html = '';
http.get(options, function(res) {
res.on('data', function(data) {
    // collect the data chunks to the variable named "html"
    html += data;
}).on('end', function() {
    // the whole of webpage data has been collected. parsing time!
    var title = $(html).find('title').text();
    console.log(title);
 });
});
```

References of jQuery in Node.js** :

- http://quaintous.com/2015/07/31/jqery-node-mystery/
- http://www.hacksparrow.com/jquery-with-node-js.html

Comment: Doesn't work for me...     C:\...\\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:31
  throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );                                            ^
Error: jQuery requires a window with a document  at module.exports (C:\...\WebContent\resources\js\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:31:12)

Comment: var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var window = jsdom.jsdom().defaultView;

jsdom.jQueryify(window, "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js", function () {
  var $ = window.$;
  $("body").prepend("<h1>The title</h1>");
  console.log($("h1").html());
});

Answer (score 8):

You have to get the window using the new JSDOM API.

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { window } = new jsdom.JSDOM(`...`);
var $ = require("jquery")(window);
```

Comment: the .JSDOM(`...`) should be .JSDOM("<!DOCTYPE html>") for HTML5 support?

Answer (score 6):

First of all install it

```
npm install jquery -S
```

After installing it, you can use it as below

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;
$(selector).hide();
```

You can check out a full tutorial that I wrote here: https://medium.com/fbdevclagos/how-to-use-jquery-on-node-df731bd6abc7

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING**

This solution, as mentioned by [Golo Roden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333873/golo-roden) is not *correct*. It is just a quick fix to help people to have their actual jQuery code running using a Node app structure, but it's not Node philosophy because the jQuery is still running on the client side instead of on the server side. I'm sorry for giving a wrong answer.

---

You can also render Jade with node and put your jQuery code inside. Here is the code of the jade file:

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Holamundo!
    script(type='text/javascript', src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js')
  body
    h1#headTitle Hello, World
    p#content This is an example of Jade.
    script
      $('#headTitle').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
      $('#content').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

My working code is:

```
npm install jquery
```

and then:

```
global.jQuery   = require('jquery');
global.$        = global.jQuery;
```

or if the window is present, then:

```
typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this;
window.jQuery   = require('jquery');
window.$        = window.jQuery;
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these solutions has helped me in my Electron App.

My solution (workaround):

```
npm install jquery
```

In your `index.js` file:

```
var jQuery = $ = require('jquery');
```

In your `.js` files write yours jQuery functions in this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

The module [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) is a great tool. But if you want to evaluate entire pages and do some funky stuff on them server side I suggest running them in their own context:

```
vm.runInContext
```

So things like `require` / `CommonJS` on site will not blow your Node process itself.

You can find documentation [here](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As of jsdom v10, .env() function is deprecated. I did it like below after trying a lot of things to require jquery:

```js
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;

var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
```

Hope this helps you or anyone who has been facing these types of issues.

Comment: `TypeError: JSDOM is not a constructor`

Comment: If you're running jQuery at Node side, firstly, install jquery and jsdom using npm install. Then, add above lines in the file you're trying to use jquery selector in. For instance, I used a `$.each`. I just included these lines and then did it like below: 
`$.each(errors, function (ind,error) { res.send(error.msg);console.log(error.msg); });` 
Hope this helps !!

Comment: Somehow jsdom had decided not to install at all. I guess I'm still figuring npm out. Thanks@

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `jQuery` can be used with `Node.js`.

Steps to include jQuery in node project:-

`npm i jquery --save`
Include jquery in codes

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';

const $ = jQuery;
```

I do use jquery in node.js projects all the time specifically in the chrome extension's project.

e.g. https://github.com/fxnoob/gesture-control-chrome-extension/blob/master/src/default_plugins/tab.js

Answer (score 1):

I did it manually easy way without any additional packages or code.

```
npm i jquery
```

then I copy the `jquery.min.js` file from `node_modules/jquery/dist` directory to `public/js`

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { console.log( "ready!" ); });
</script>
```

And it will work. TEST  IT

**Note** copy/pasting the file is not the ideal thing, you could enable the file as a static file by enabling it as a static so expressJS could read it. But it is easier for me to just copy it to the static public directory.

Answer (score -1):

No. It's going to be quite a big effort to port a browser environment to node.

Another approach, that I'm currently investigating for unit testing, is to create "Mock" version of jQuery that provides callbacks whenever a selector is called.

This way you could unit test your jQuery plugins without actually having a DOM. You'll still have to test in real browsers to see if your code works in the wild, but if you discover browser specific issues, you can easily "mock" those in your unit tests as well.

I'll push something to github.com/felixge once it's ready to show.

Comment: I like this idea... it's should be quite easy to do.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/), it allows hybrid browserjs and nodejs.

Before, I tried to use canvas2d in nodejs, but finally I gave up. It's not supported by nodejs default, and too hard to install it (many many ... dependeces).
Until I use Electron, I can easily use all my previous browserjs code, even WebGL, and pass the result value(eg. result base64 image data) to nodejs code.

Answer (score -8):

Not that I know of. The DOM is a client side thing (jQuery doesn't parse the HTML, but the DOM).

Here are some current Node.js projects:

https://github.com/ry/node/wiki (https://github.com/nodejs/node)

And SimonW's [djangode](http://github.com/simonw/djangode) is pretty damn cool...

Comment: I wish it was possible. I already tried including jquery on a node.js project and of course it didn't work. jQuery is based on document/window.

Rhino is capable of running jQuery server side:

http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/ 

I'm going to look for more parsers. Maybe there is one that doesn't depend on the browser.

Comment: @John: the only reason jQuery can run on Rhino is because of this project: http://github.com/jeresig/env-js/blob/master/src/env.js  It simulates a small portion of the DOM and the JavaScript runtime. It relies on Java apis so is a no-go for Node.js (which uses V8/C++).

Comment: @Nosredna While this may have been true when you wrote it, it is clearly not true any more. I suggest that you delete your answer now.

Answer (score -19):

An alternative is to use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).  It should provide what you might have wanted server-side from JQuery.

Comment: Can you explain?  jQuery provides tons of DOM manipulation/traversing/filtering APIs. Underscore looks like generic library utilities having nothing to do with the DOM.

Comment: Same here, I do not see how this is relevant the two are complements, not alternatives

Comment: This answer is not totally wrong. jQuery and Underscore do overlap: they both provide features such as forEach.

Comment: I mean: `$.each()` and `_.each()`.

Comment: -1 They have overlapping functionality but Underscore is not a jQuery replacement.

Comment: The question is asking about DOM manipulation/selectors though.

Comment: This is actually the answer I am looking for. I, for one, want to have the utility functions that jQuery provides without all the heavyweight DOM features.