# Javascript framework on Node.js

Tags: jquery, prototype, extjs, dojo, node.js

I wonder which of these javascript frameworks - officially - works on Node.js:

- jQuery
- Prototype
- Mootools
- Dojo
- Extjs

Comment: "Officially" according to who?

Comment: The javascript framework providers. however, i havent read anything about node.js on their site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js) for jQuery compatibility.

[This link](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-nodejs) has some info on MooTools with Node.js

[Another link](http://supercollider.dk/2010/01/bootstrapping-dojo-in-node-221) with some info on Dojo and Node.js

Answer (score 2):

The [node modules list](https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/modules#commonjs-compat) lists a [patched version of dojo](https://github.com/novemberborn/dojo) as one of the "CommonJS compatible modules that can be used with node".

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to go to [node toolbelt](http://toolbox.no.de/) to discover problem-sorted (auth, db, routing, templating, ...) libraries

Also, remember that node.js is server side : DOM and style manipulations libraries such as jQuery are quite useless in that case.