# Match URL Scheme with Port

Tags: regex, url

I'm trying to match the the URI / URL scheme (e.x. ftp, http, https) using this regex `^(.*:)` . The problem is that my url has a port number so the `:` to connote server connection in the scheme isn't the only one in the URL there is also `:80`. How do I just match the scheme using regex?

Given this example:

```
http://video.google.co.uk/videoplay?docid=-7246927612831078230&hl=en#00h02m30s
```

I would like regex to just match:

```
http
```

I'm not interested in something like

```
^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)
```

I know this would work it, it is limiting however. It wouldn't give me `mailto, tel, ssh, etc.`

Comment: must you use regex? which language are you using? in java for instance you could do `URL url = new URL("http://video.google.co.uk/videoplay?docid=-7246927612831078230&hl=en#00h02m30s");  System.out.println(url.getProtocol());`

Comment: I'm trying to create something like this function for server-side javascript (node.js), perhaps one already exists, I don't know what to look for.

Comment: again know nothing about node.js but seems here that someone is using document.create .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299623/169277

Comment: Yeah they are parsing a html file and creating a document from it. I could do this, but then my lib would be dependent on two others. I wanna keep it simple.

Comment: yp that would be an overhead for this kind of usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that `^[^:]+` works.