# Uppercase first letter of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched over the web and I can't find anything to help me. I want to make the first letter of each word upper case within a variable.

So far I have tried:

```
toUpperCase();
```

And I didn't have any luck, as it uppercases all letters.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086390/jquery-camelcase

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Use the [.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function to replace the lowercase letters that begin a word with the capital letter.

```js
var str = "hello, world!";
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
alert(str); //Displays "Hello, World!"
```

---

If you are dealing with word characters other than just a-z, then the following (more complicated) regular expression might better suit your purposes.

```js
var str = "петр данилович björn über ñaque αλφα";
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/^[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]|\s[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
alert(str); //Displays "Петр Данилович Björn Über Ñaque Αλφα"
```

Comment: This doesn't work with names like `Björn Lüchinger`, this becomes `BjöRn LüChinger`. Any fix for this?

Comment: Works great! Any hints on what the modification should be if I just wanted to convert to uppercase the first character of the string? (instead of every single word)

Comment: @andufo Sure, that's actually much simpler to do. Just use `str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)`

Comment: @PeterOlson thanks for the answer! I ended using `var first = str.slice(0, str.indexOf(' ')); str = first.toLowerCase().replace(/^[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]|\s[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]/g, function(letter) { return letter.toUpperCase(); }) + str.substr(first.length);` to cover special characters as well.

Comment: This solution make uppercase in the middle become lowercase, eg: `GNU's not unix` it will produce `Gnu's Not Unix`

Answer (score 82):

A much easier way:

`$('#test').css('textTransform', 'capitalize');`

I have to give [Rafael Herscovici some credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122402/uppercase-first-letter-of-variable/6897635#6897635) for leading me down the right path. It is far simpler than whatever you guys are proposing.

Comment: This only changes the visual representation of the string and not the string value itself.

Comment: You can't apply this to variables fetched from DB though, but for other instaces this method very clean

Comment: Note: `text-transform:capitalize` will not affect ALL CAPS.

Comment: What if the string (variable) must be used for some operation other than just displaying?

Comment: note that it will save the input with the capitalize, it will only convert it in the view

Answer (score 34):

http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords:569 has a good example

```
function ucwords (str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/^([a-z])|\s+([a-z])/g, function ($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

(omitted function comment from source for brevity. please see linked source for details)

EDIT: Please note that this function uppercases the first letter of each word (as your question asks) and not just the first letter of a string (as your question title asks)

Comment: This works better than the accepted one solution that capitalizes words in a sentence after apostrophe, so e.g. "I'm an example" becomes "I'M An Example"

Comment: Does not work if you have an underscore in your original string, please add it to your REGEX for better performance. TY

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant That would be answering a different question. Interpreting an underscore as a word separator(or general blank space) is fine, but isn't what OP was asking for... and might even break his use case.

Comment: ucwords() sucks. It doesn't works with Unicode (particularly with cyrillic, greek and other central European alphabets).
Better use mb_convert_case() on back-end, eg:

mb_convert_case($_POST['name'], MB_CASE_TITLE, 'utf-8');

Answer (score 17):

Here is a pure JavaScript solution (no jQuery):

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  strVal = '';
  str = str.split(' ');
  for (var chr = 0; chr < str.length; chr++) {
    strVal += str[chr].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str[chr].substring(1, str[chr].length) + ' '
  }
  return strVal
}

console.log(capitalize('hello world'));
```

Comment: thanks bro, just want to correct something. this `c < str.length;` should be `chr < str.length;`

Answer (score 14):

I imagine you could use substring() and toUpperCase() to pull out the first character, uppercase it, and then replace the first character of your string with the result.

```
myString = "cheeseburger";
firstChar = myString.substring( 0, 1 ); // == "c"
firstChar.toUpperCase();
tail = myString.substring( 1 ); // == "heeseburger"
myString = firstChar + tail; // myString == "Cheeseburger"
```

I think that should work for you.  Another thing to consider is that if this data is being displayed, you can add a class to its container that has the CSS property "text-transform: capitalize".

Comment: shouldn't  there be like firstChar = firstChar.toUpperCase(); ? I tried the code in Node.js and I had to do that or nothing changed!

Answer (score 11):

It is as simple as the following:

```
string = 'test';
newString = string[0].toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
alert(newString);
```

Answer (score 10):

To do this, you don't really even need JavaScript if you're going to use

```javascript
$('#test').css('text-transform', 'capitalize');
```

Do this as CSS like:

```css
#test,h1,h2,h3 { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

Or do it as a class and apply that class to wherever you need it:

```css
.ucwords { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your answer is suggesting an alternative (that might be perfectly valid in some use cases), but does not really answer the question. As I understood the question, the author wanted to actually transform the Javascript variable, and not just it's visual representation.

Comment: Yeah, but other people who come to this question might be okay with javascript OR css answers, like me, and this was really helpful...

Answer (score 7):

Ever heard of `substr()`?

For a starter:

```
$("#test").text($("#test").text().substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+$("#test").text().substr(1,$("#test").text().length));
```

Thanks to [@FelixKling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122402/javascript-jquery-uppercase-first-letter-of-variable#comment5753220_5122567) for the tip:

```
$("#test").text(function(i, text) {
    return text.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + text.substr(1);
});
```

Comment: Instead of calling the `text()` **four** times, pass a function to `text()`: `$("#test").text(function(i, text) { return text.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+text.substr(1);});`

Comment: digging up old corps here, but if it was known the content goes into an element, it would be much easier to use: `$('#test').style.textTransform='capitalize';`

Comment: Close, @Dementic, but it should be:

`$('#test').css('textTransform', 'capitalize');`

BTW, this is the best answer here. I'll submit it as an answer.

Comment: @vbullinger - dont judge my code when i write it drunk as hell :)
and i love js, not jq, so my code is wrong, but not too much `document.getElementById('test').style.textTransform='capitalize';`

Answer (score 6):

Building on [Peter Olson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122402/uppercase-first-letter-of-variable/5122461#5122461), I took a more object-oriented approach without jQuery:

```
String.prototype.ucwords = function() {
    return this.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
}

alert("hello, world!".ucwords()); // Displays "Hello, World!"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LzaYH/1/

Comment: This is really the most proper way, in my opinion.  I would call it `toUpperCaseWords` in keeping in line with javascript's `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way

```
let str = "hiren raiyani"
str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?<= )[^\s]|^./g, a => a.toUpperCase());
```

User-defined function:

```
function capitalize(str){
    return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?<= )[^\s]|^./g, a => a.toUpperCase());
}
```

Output: **Hiren Raiyani**

Use code as your user-defined function or direct.

Comment: BEWARE: This crashes mobile safari! And potentially others! https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Answer (score 4):

```
var mystring = "hello World"
mystring = mystring.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + 
mystring.substring(1,mystring.length)

console.log(mystring) //gives you Hello World
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var ar = 'foo bar spam egg'.split(/\W/);
for(var i=0; i<ar.length; i++) {
  ar[i] = ar[i].substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + ar[i].substr(1,ar[i].length-1) 
}
ar.join(' '); // Foo Bar Spam Egg
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this simple code with the features of ucwords in PHP.

```
function ucWords(text) {
    return text.split(' ').map((txt) => (txt.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + txt.substring(1, txt.length))).join(' ');
}
ucWords('hello WORLD');
```

It will keep the Upper Cases unchanged.

Comment: But this question is tagged with JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Use the below function:

```
const capitalize = (s) => {
  if (typeof s !== 'string')
    return ''
  return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
}

capitalize('test') // 'Test'
capitalize('name') // 'Name'
```

Answer (score 2):

Based completely on [Rafael Herscovici's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122402/uppercase-first-letter-of-variable/6897635#6897635), this solution is ready to call with a simple jQuery method, 'ucwords'...

```
$.extend({
    ucwords : function(str) {
        strVal = '';
        str = str.split(' ');
        for (var chr = 0; chr < str.length; chr++) {
            strVal += str[chr].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str[chr].substring(1, str[chr].length) + ' '
        }
        return strVal
    }
});
```

#### Example:

This can be called using the method

```
var string = "this is a test";
string = $.ucwords(string); // Returns "This Is A Test"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text-transform: capitalize;` for this work.

#### HTML

```html
<input type="text" style="text-transform: capitalize;" />
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var asdf = "WERTY UIOP";
    $('input').val(asdf.toLowerCase());
});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/w4WqQ/1/)

Note: It's only changing the visual representation of the string. If you *alert()* this string, it will always show the original value of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Without JQuery

```
String.prototype.ucwords = function() {
    str = this.trim();
    return str.replace(/(^([a-zA-Z\p{M}]))|([ -][a-zA-Z\p{M}])/g, function(s){
        return s.toUpperCase();
    });
};

console.log('hello world'.ucwords()); // Display Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The easiest way to uppercase the first letter in JavaScript

```
var string = "made in india";

string = string.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter){return letter.toUpperCase();});

alert(string);
```

Result:

"Made In India"

Answer (score 1):

There sure are a lot of ways to do this!

One thing that I think people forget is that strings are arrays of characters.  So, the first letter of any string will be the 'zeroth' element of its array:

```
let word = 'interesting';
console.log(word[0]);
// 'i'
```

The simplest way to take advantage of this fact for the purpose of uppercasing the first letter (afaik) would be:

```
let word = 'interesting';
let titleCase = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
console.log(titleCase);
// 'Interesting'
```

...or as a function:

```
function toTitleCase(word) {
    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
}
```

Comment: The first in all answers that has a decent explaination and ANSWERS THE QUESTION. The question was about making sure that the first letter in a variable is uppercase. So NOT CSS solutions and NOT uppercase every word. Where the H*LL are the moderators???

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple answer:

```js
let str = 'this is a string';

let result = str.replace(/\b\w/g, x => x.toUpperCase());

console.log(result); // This Is A String
```

Answer (score 0):

The string to lower before capitalizing the first letter.

(Both use jQuery syntax)

```
function CapitaliseFirstLetter(elementId) {
    var txt = $("#" + elementId).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#" + elementId).val(txt.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    }));
}
```

In addition a function to Capitalise the WHOLE string:

```
function CapitaliseAllText(elementId) {
    var txt = $("#" + elementId).val();
    $("#" + elementId).val(txt.toUpperCase());
}
```

Syntax to use on a textbox's click event:

```
onClick="CapitaliseFirstLetter('TextId'); return false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code -

```
function ucword(str){
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/(^([a-zA-Z\p{M}]))|([ -][a-zA-Z\p{M}])/g, function(replace_latter) { 
        return replace_latter.toUpperCase();
    });  //Can use also /\b[a-z]/g
    return str;  //First letter capital in each word
}

var uc = ucword("good morning. how are you?");
alert(uc);
```

Comment: What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```html
<input class="capitalize" name="Address" type="text" value="" />
```

JavaScript with jQuery:

```javascript
$(".capitalize").bind("keyup change", function (e) {
    if ($(this).val().length == 1)
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    $(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(/\s[\p{L}a-z]/g, function (letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    }))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD";
str = str.replace(
        /([A-Z])([A-Z]+)/g,
        function (a, w1, w2) {
            return w1 + w2.toLowerCase();
        });
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Unicode-safe ucwords() function, which additionally respects double-lastnames like Russian Засс-Ранцев and some noble names like Honoré de Balzac, d'Artagnan, Vincent van Gogh, Otto von Bismarck, Sulaymān ibn Dāwūd, etc.:

```
String.prototype.ucwords = function() {
  return this.toLowerCase()
    .replace(/(^|\s|\-)[^\s$]/g, function(m) {
       return m.toUpperCase();
    })
    // French, Arabic and some noble names...
    .replace(/\s(Of|De|Van|Von|Ibn|Из|Ван|Фон|Ибн)\s/g, function(m) { // Honoré de Balzac, Vincent van Gogh, Otto von Bismarck, Sulaymān ibn Dāwūd etc.
       return m.toLowerCase();
    })
    .replace(/(^|\s)(D|Д)(['’][^\s$])/g, function(m, p1, p2, p3) { // D'Artagnan or d'Artagnan / Д’Артаньян или д’Артаньян
       return p1 + (p1 === "" ? p2/*.toUpperCase()*/ : p2.toLowerCase()) + p3.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var country = $('#country').val();

var con = country[0].toUpperCase();

ctr = country.replace(country[0], con);
```

There isn't any need to create any function, just jugaaar.

Comment: What is *"jugaaar"*?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the method should not convert any other letters than just the very first or the very first of any letter.

My solution for that are the following regexes:

```js
function capitalize( str ){
    return str.replace(/^\w/, (s) => s.toUpperCase() );
}

function capitalizeAll( str ){
    return str.replace(/(\b\w)/g, (s) => s.toUpperCase() );
}

let test = 'hello world';

capitalize( test ); // Hello world
capitalizeAll( test ); // Hello World
```