# Change Text box value to Uppercase the first letter of every word separated by (.)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the value of textbox using jQuery/JavaScript before the form get submitted (before button clicked) when a user typed:

will.smith to Will.Smith

I have used the below code which only convert it Uppercase (entire string):

```
$('input[type=text]').val (function () {
    return this.value.toUpperCase();
})
```

Keeping in mind I don't want to change it visually using CSS.

I hope someone can give me an idea on the same.

Comment: Please show what code you have tried.

Comment: @RJM Plz check my post again :) ... hope you can help me figure this out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uppercase first letter of variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122402/uppercase-first-letter-of-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
textBox.value = textBox.value.split('.').map(function(word) {
  return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
}).join('.');
```

Or since you are using jQuery:

```
$('input[type=text]').val(function() {
  return this.value.split('.').map(function(word) {
    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
  }).join('.');
});
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the value? But I think you get the idea.

Also, to be on the safe side you could do something like `word.substr(1).toLowerCase()` which would make sure that only the first letter is capitalized.

Comment: what exactly I need to do with the value, I want to make sure before the form get submitted, whatever values typed by the user it should convert the same to exp: Will.Smith in the textbox

Comment: I think you can do something like `this.value = this.value.split('.......`. That will update the textbox's text content.

Comment: thanks for the elaborated answer. Just one more thing, I can make the above code get executed when a user is typing in the textbox or it's not doable u think?

Comment: You can. You would add an event listener that when the textbox changes. See https://api.jquery.com/change/.