# CSS Capitalize First Letter In All Caps Word

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to capitalize the first letter only of a word that is all caps using CSS?

So change "TESTING" to "Testing"?

```
<span class = "capitalize">TESTING</span>
```

The css property text-transform: capitalize doesn't work (capitalizes the first letter but ignores the rest).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible with just CSS, here's how:

```css
.capitalize {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.capitalize:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<span class = "capitalize">TESTING</span>
```

> You'll notice I added `display:inline-block`, this is because:
>
> "A first line has meaning only in a block-container box, therefore the ::first-letter pseudo-element has an effect only on elements with a display value of block, inline-block, table-cell, list-item or table-caption." [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```
<style>
    p.capitaliseFirstLetterOnly {
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    p.capitaliseFirstLetterOnly::first-letter{
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<p class="capitaliseFirstLetterOnly">TESTING.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery as follows:

```
<span class="capitalize">MYTEXT</span>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var txt = $(".capitalize").text().toLowerCase();
            txt = txt.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (letter) {
                return letter.toUpperCase();
            });
            $(".capitalize").text(txt); 
        });        
    </script>
```

Reference:

[Uppercase first letter of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122402/uppercase-first-letter-of-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can try identify it with Js.

Answer (score 0):

```
.capitalize::first-letter {
     text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5wbe2ugq/

There's no way to see in CSS if the first letter is capitalized, however you can make sure of it via:

```
.capitalize::first-letter {
     text-transform: capitalize;
}

.capitalize {
     text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style>
.capitalize{
  text-transform:lowercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
.capitalize::first-letter {
     text-transform:capitalize; 
}
</style>
<span class = "capitalize">TESTING</span>
```

Make sure to add *display:inline-block* because the element **span** does not work with :first-letter unlike with p,div,tables, etc. If you are using an element which has block by default, then you don't need to put a *display:inline-block* just like the code below.

```
 <style>
.capitalize{
  text-transform:lowercase; 
}
.capitalize::first-letter {
     text-transform:capitalize; 
}
</style>
<div class = "capitalize">TESTING</div>
```

Cheers,