# javascript capitalization

Tags: javascript, jquery, capitalization

```
var font_name = $(".font").val();
```

I have this in my JavaScript code. In my html I have an input form with the class `.font`.

I want to capitalize the first letter of each word in `.font`, so for example if someone types in `Lucida sans` it'll turn into `Lucida Sans`. I couldn't find a jQuery method that does it for you so I guess I have to use actual JavaScript but I really have no idea how.

```
var font_first = font_name.substr(0,1);
var font = font_first.toUpperCase() + font_name.substr(1, font_name.length - 1);
```

I used this to capitalize the first letter of the whole font name but as I said I need to capitalize the first letter of each word.

Comment: Look for each space, then capitalize the next character...

Comment: Here is a question covering this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086390/jquery-camelcase

Answer (score 4):

Can you not just use CSS?

```
.font {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

In jQuery:

```
$(".font").css("text-transform","capitalize");
```

Comment: It may just be me being biased... but I'd probably go as far as saying it's worth being an accepted answer! (Unless the OP can give a reason for this not being suitable/possible of course)

Answer (score 2):

You can split on spaces, map the "uppercasing" function to each piece, and join them back together.

```
var font_name = $(".font").val();
font_name = font_name.split(" ")
                     .map(function(a) {return a.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.substr(1);})
                     .join(" ");
```

Alternatively, see [`ucwords` by PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords:569)

Answer (score 1):

In plain javascript:

```js
function firstcap(str) {
  var len = str.length;
  var re = /^\s$/;
  var special = true; // signalizes whether previous char is special or not
  for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (code>=97 && code<=122 && special) {
      str = str.substr(0, i) + String.fromCharCode(code-32) + str.substr(i+1);
      special = false;
    }
    else if (re.test(str[i])) {
      special = true;
    }
  }
  return str;
}

alert(firstcap('lucida sans'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "hello world";
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b./g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
alert(str);
```

from here [stack](http://www.google.sk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jquery%20first%20letter%20capital&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122402/javascript-jquery-uppercase-first-letter-of-variable&ei=L1z3T8WANI7S4QT-_5yKBw&usg=AFQjCNEs8F1QOkyt3iO_epWLuUNa3jgzQw&cad=rja)

Comment: that's true, but he can write regex as he wish, it's just example

Comment: It's just a rant, but now the regex will capture whitespace in 'Lucida Sans' as well. ) It won't be uppercased, of course, but still... )

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JavaScript function I just finished writing. Since I first checked StackOverflow to see if this JavaScript was around, but wasn't easily found, I'll post it for you guys to use. Hope it helps you guys, if it does, uptick me :)

```
var FormatMyTitle = function(UnformattedData) {
    var OutgoingData = UnformattedData;
    if (UnformattedData.indexOf("") != -1) {
        var OptionNameParts = UnformattedData.split(' ');
        for (var i=0; i<OptionNameParts.length; i++) {
            var OptionNamePieces = OptionNameParts[i].split('');
            if (OptionNamePieces.length >= 1) {
                var FirstLetter = ''+OptionNamePieces[0]+'';
                OptionNamePieces[0] = FirstLetter.toUpperCase();
            }
            OptionNameParts[i] = OptionNamePieces.join('');
        }
        OutgoingData = OptionNameParts.join(' ');
    }
    return OutgoingData;
};
```

And you would use it like so, for instance, using your original variable(font_name):

```
var FormattedTitle = FormatMyTitle(font_name);
```