# String modification issue in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like "word_count". How can I transform it to "WordCount" in an elegant way using JavaScript? My decision seems too complicated to me. I'll be very grateful for your help.

Comment: `My decision seems too complicated to me.`. Could you share it with us? Maybe it could be improved.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086390/jquery-camelcase) is similar and might provide the information you are looking for

Comment: Try using the function I created which I put in my response.  It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function titleCase(str)
{
    return str.split("_")
        .map(function (s) { return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1); })
        .join("");
}
```

Comment: Functional programming FTW! :)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this](http://jamesroberts.name/blog/2010/02/22/string-functions-for-javascript-trim-to-camel-case-to-dashed-and-to-underscore/). I don't want to just copy paste everything here, but it seems to be just what you're looking for.

Here is the function modified to fit your request:

```
String.prototype.toCamel = function(){
    return this.replace(/((^|\_)[a-z])/g, function($1){
                return $1.toUpperCase().replace('_','');});
};
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fp76Z/) it is in action.

Comment: Note, this doesn't replace the first character with a capital.

Comment: Note that camel case is `wordCount`, not `WordCount` as the op wanted.

Comment: This would be better if you could actually select/copy the text. Pictures of words are a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I was merely showing OP where in the blog post to look.

Comment: They came here for answers. Here.

Comment: My downvote was because it didn't work. I removed it and +1 because you have a working answer.

Comment: I added `.toLowerCase()` to the end of the outer return to ensure it starts with lower case but then realised that this function is not idempotent and will make lowercase existing uppercased characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to match either a letter at the start of the string or a letter after an underscore, and use a callback to turn the letter into uppercase:

```
s = s.replace(/(?:^|_)([a-z])/g, function(m, g){
  return g.toUpperCase();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ByU6P/

Comment: You could also use the argument passed due to the group: http://jsfiddle.net/ByU6P/2/.

Comment: @pimvdb: Yes, that is a bit cleaner. :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple, like this:

```
var string = "word_count".split("_");
for(var i = 0; i<string.length;i++) {
    string[i] = string[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string[i].substr(1);
}
var myNiceString = string.join();
```

If you want to add it to the String object, you can do this:

```
String.prototype.titleCase = function() {
    var split = this.split("_");
    for(var i = 0; i<split.length;i++) {
        split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].substr(1);
    }
    return split.join("");
}
```

You'd call it like `"word_count".titleCase();`

Comment: Strings are immutable - `toUpperCase` won't change `string[i]`.

Comment: He's looking for title casing, not camel casing.

Comment: @pmvdb: Good point, I've edited to account for that. **Anthony Mills**, it was title casing, but I named the function wrong--edited to correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like the following:

```
var Pascalize = function(word) {
    var x = word;
    result = '';
    if(-1 != word.indexOf('_')) {
        x = word.split('_');
        for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
            result += x[i].substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + x[i].substr(1);
        }
    }
    if('' == result) { result = word; }
    return result;
};

var PascalCaseString = Pascalize("this_is_a_test");
// PascalCaseString value is now 'ThisIsATest'
```

**[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/GjuPK/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "word_count";
var re = /\b(.)([^_]+)_(.)/;
var newWord = str.replace(re, function(m,f,t,l){ return f.toUpperCase() + t + l.toUpperCase();})
console.log(newWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you could do the following:

```
var result = '';
$.each('word_count'.split('_'), function(idx,elem){
  result = result + elem.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + elem.substr(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

New version (works with any amount of `_`):

```
function fixString(sString) {

    var aWords = sString.split("_"),
        sResults = "";

    for (var i in aWords)
        sResults += aWords[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + aWords[i].slice(1);

    return sResults;

}
```

The compressed form:

```
function fixString(c){var d=c.split("_"),a="";for(var b in d){a+=d[b].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+d[b].slice(1)}return a};
```

Old:

```
function fixString(sString) {

    return sString.replace(/(.*)_(.*)/, function(sWhole, $1, $2, sWTF) {

        return ucfirst($1) + ucfirst($2);

    } )

    function ucfirst (str) {

        str += '';

        var f = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

        return f + str.substr(1);

    }

}
```

... or the compressed version:

```
function fixString(b){return b.replace(/(.*)_(.*)/,function(e,c,f,d){return a(c)+a(f)});function a(d){d+="";var c=d.charAt(0).toUpperCase();return c+d.substr(1)}};
```

Of course, this is used like `fixString("word_count")` which results in your desired `WordCount`.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at all the answer and none did precisely what I wanted. I wanted an *idempotent* function which converted to camelCase (not PascalCase) and I liked the String prototype extension approach (although obviously this isn't always the best medicine).

Anyway, here's where I ended up:

```
String.prototype.camelize = function(){
    var pascalCase = this.replace(/((^|\_)[a-z])/g, function($1){
        return $1.toUpperCase().replace('_','');
    });
    return pascalCase.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + this.slice(1);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var aStringLike = "word_count";

// magic follows

aStringLike = "WordCount";
```