# Writing to a particular div in node js

Tags: node.js

I have this simple file hello.html and looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  p { background:yellow; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="thediv">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using `fs` module to write to my file like this

```
var fs = require('fs');

var randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*100393)+433334);

fs.createReadStream('test.txt').pipe(fs.createWriteStream(randomnumber+'.txt'));

fs.writeFile(randomnumber+".txt", "Lorem ipsum"+randomnumber, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }
}); 

console.log(randomnumber);
```

I want to write

```
<article>
<p> lorem ipsum </p>
</article>
```

to the div with the id `thediv`.Is the `fs` module used for this kind of thing or is there a module more suited for this task?.

Comment: have you tried template engines like [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) or [ejs](http://embeddedjs.com/)? They do exactly what you want. Combine html templates with dynamic data.

Comment: I am not looking for a templating solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only answer to get an HTML parser, parse the file into a DOM, make the adjustments and then save the DOM back to a file. Here's a question that answers where to [find an HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372972/how-do-i-parse-a-html-page-with-node-js).