# Node.js HTMLParser iterating more than one time

Tags: node.js

I have this simple HTMLParser in Node.js using the http module:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {  
    var title1 = chunk.indexOf("<title>");  
    var title2 = chunk.indexOf("</title>"); 
    var titl = chunk.substring(title1 + 7);
    var result = titl.substring(0, titl.indexOf("</title>"));
    console.log("Title is : " + result);
  });
req.end();
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.end();
```

and when executed, iterates more than once, so I get this output in the command line and it varies but always iterates more than once.

```
Title is: Google
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
 Title is:
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW if your end goal is to have an actual usable parser, you're probably better off using something like [`cheerio`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7373003/1481489 for information on better ways to parse HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` event may fire more than once while information is incoming. You need to store the incoming `Buffer` (i.e. `chunk`) into your own buffer and parse when the response is complete. That is why it is referred to as a *chunk* - it is partial data.

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  var content = '';
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    content += chunk; // concatenate incoming data chunk to a response buffer
  });
  res.once('end', function() { // once the response has ended (it is complete)
    var title1 = content.indexOf("<title>");  // parse
    var title2 = content.indexOf("</title>"); 
    var titl = content.substring(title1 + 7);
    var result = titl.substring(0, titl.indexOf("</title>"));
    console.log("Title is : " + result);
  });
});
```

You may also want to clean up the response event `data` handler on `end` as well:

```
function storeChunk(chunk) {
  content += chunk;
}
res.on('data',storeChunk);
res.once('end',function() {
  res.removeListener('data',storeChunk);
  // ...
});
```

Comment: "will fire more than once" is a bit strong. It *could* fire more than once.