# how to get at this data

Tags: html, excel, web-scraping, vba

I am looking to scrape the three items that are highlighted and bordered from the html sample below. I've also highlighted a few markers that look useful.

How would you do this?

[image]

**A Solution**

Ok so this wasn't a great question and I'm actually surprised it didn't get down-voted more! Oh well, here are some bread crumbs for someone else.

Three of the four items of info I want are the inner text of a span element with a known id (ie, $0.83 for "yfs_l10_gm150220c00036500"), so I the following helper class seems to be a decent and direct shot:

```html
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' GetSpanTextForId
'
' Returns the inner text from a span element known by the passed id
'
' param doc:     the source HTMLDocument
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetSpanTextForId(ByRef doc As HTMLDocument, ByVal spanId As String) As Double
'   Error Handling
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim sRoutine        As String
    sRoutine = cModule & ".GetSpanTextForId"
     
    CheckArgNotNothing doc, "doc"
    CheckArgNotBadString spanId, "spanId"
'   Procedure
    Dim oSpan As HTMLSpanElement
    Set oSpan = doc.getElementById(spanId)
    Check Not oSpan Is Nothing, "Could not find span with id: " & Bracket(spanId)
    GetSpanTextForId = oSpan.innerText
    
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Select Case DspErrMsg(sRoutine)
         Case Is = vbAbort:  Stop: Resume    'Debug mode - Trace
         Case Is = vbRetry:  Resume          'Try again
         Case Is = vbIgnore:                 'End routine
     End Select


End Function
```

The only item not directly known by a span is the OpenInterest which is part of a table that is the 2nd child of an element with an id. The following methods return the cell that immediately follows the cell with the text I want (ie, "Open Interest")

```html
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' GetOpenInterest
'
' The latest available Open Interest.
'
' param doc:     the source HTMLDocument
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetOpenInterest(ByRef doc As HTMLDocument) As Integer
    Dim tbl As IHTMLTable
    Set tbl = GetSummaryDataTable(doc, 1)
    Dim k As Integer
    k = mWebScrapeHelpers.GetCellNumberForTextStartingWith(tbl, "Open Interest:")
    GetOpenInterest = CInt(mWebScrapeHelpers.GetCellTextFromCellNumber(tbl, k + 1))
End Function


Function GetCellNumberForTextStartingWith(ByRef tbl As IHTMLTable, ByRef s As String) As Integer
'   Error Handling
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim sRoutine        As String
    sRoutine = cModule & ".GetCellNumberForTextStartingWith"
    
    CheckArgNotNothing tbl, "tbl"
    
'   Procedure
    Dim tblCell As HTMLTableCell
    Dim k As Integer

    For Each tblCell In tbl.Cells
        If tblCell.innerText Like ("*" & s) Then
            GetCellNumberForTextStartingWith = k
            Exit Function
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Next
    
    ' if we got here it was not found so
    GetCellNumberForTextStartingWith = -1
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Select Case DspErrMsg(sRoutine)
         Case Is = vbAbort:  Stop: Resume    'Debug mode - Trace
         Case Is = vbRetry:  Resume          'Try again
         Case Is = vbIgnore:                 'End routine
     End Select
     
End Function

Function GetCellTextFromCellNumber(ByRef tbl As IHTMLTable, ByRef nbr As Integer) As String
'   Error Handling
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim sRoutine        As String
    sRoutine = cModule & ".GetCellNumberForTextStartingWith"
    
    CheckArgNotNothing tbl, "tbl"
    Check tbl.Cells.Length > 0, "table is empty"
    Check tbl.Cells.Length >= nbr, "table only has " & tbl.Cells.Length & " cells; can't get cell number " & nbr
    
'   Procedure
    GetCellTextFromCellNumber = tbl.Cells(nbr).innerText
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Select Case DspErrMsg(sRoutine)
         Case Is = vbAbort:  Stop: Resume    'Debug mode - Trace
         Case Is = vbRetry:  Resume          'Try again
         Case Is = vbIgnore:                 'End routine
     End Select


End Function
```

These methods work fine but it does seem there are lots of different approaches that would work, including the regex parsing approach suggested as an answer. The *excellent* link by RedShift got more to the point of analyzing the html and coming up with a strategy.

Cheers

Comment: I'd start by searching "excel vba web scraping."

Comment: Have you looked at something like [this](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scraping-websites-vba.htm).

Comment: There are plenty of examples for scraping Yahoo Finance around the web and probably a few here. Suggest you use yahoo.com to look for a few suitable ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use an XML parser to get the text content first (or this: xmlString.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "") to replace all tags with empty strings), then use the following regexes to extract the information you need:

```
/-OPR\s+(\d+\.\d+)/
/Bid:\s+(\d+\.\d+)/
/Ask:\s+(\d+\.\d+)/
/Open Interest:\s+(\d+,\d+)/
```

This process can easily be done in nodejs ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7372972))or with any other language that supports regex.

---

live demo:

- Waits 1 second, then removes tags.
- Waits another second, then finds all patterns and creates a table.

```js
wait = true; // Set to false to execute instantly.

var elem = document.getElementById("parsingStuff");
var str = elem.textContent;

var keywords = ["-OPR", "Bid:", "Ask:", "Open Interest:"];
var output = {};
var timeout = 0;

if (wait) timeout = 1000;

setTimeout(function() { // Removing tags.
  elem.innerHTML = elem.textContent;
}, timeout);

if (wait) timeout = 2000;

setTimeout(function() { // Looking for patterns.
  for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    output[keywords[i]] = str.match(RegExp(keywords[i] + "\\s+(\\d+[\\.,]\\d+)"))[1];
  }

  // Creating basic table of found data.
  elem.innerHTML = "";
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  for (k in output) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    var td = document.createElement("td");

    th.style.border = "1px solid gray";
    td.style.border = "1px solid gray";

    th.textContent = k;
    td.textContent = output[k];

    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.appendChild(td);

    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  elem.appendChild(table);
}, timeout);
```

```html
<div id="parsingStuff">
  <div class="yfi_rt_quote_summary" id="yfi_rt_quote_summary">
    <div class="hd">
      <div class="title">
        <h2>GM Feb 2015 36.500 call (GM150220C00036500)</h2>
        <span class="rtq_exch">
        <span class="rtq_dash">-</span>OPR
        </span>
        <span class="wl_sign"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="yfi_rt_quote_summary_rt_top sigfig_promo_1">
      <div>
        <span class="time_rtq_ticker">

        <span id="yfs_110_gm150220c00036500">0.83</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>undefined</div>undefined
  <div class="yui-u first yfi-start-content">
    <div class="yfi_quote_summary">
      <div id="yfi_quote_summary_data" class="rtq_table">
        <table id="table1">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" width="48%">Bid:</th>
            <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

              <span id="yfs_b00_gm150220c00036500">0.76</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" width="48%">Ask:</th>
            <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

              <span id="yfs_a00_gm150220c00036500">0.90</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="table2">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" width="48%">Open Interest:</th>

            <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">11,579</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```