# Closing Frame Notification Bar in IE11 using VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

I am using VBA to automate some operations on the website. Moreover my browser is IE11.

I know that if I want to click "Save" option on the Frame Notification Bar I can use the following chunk of code:

```
Dim o as IUIAutomation
Set o = New CUIAutomation
Dim h as Long
h = ie.hwnd
Dim ie as InternetExplorer 
ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
Dim e as IUIAutomationElement
Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h) 
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition 
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")
Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement 
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd) 
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern 
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke
```

Similarly if I want to click "Open" option I can replace the word "Save" on the code above with the word "Open".

M problem is that after clicking "Save" option, I have 3 another options to click: "Open", "Open folder", "View downloads". I can also close the Frame Notification Bar by clicking the button in the right corner of the Frame Notification Bar. It is visible below:

[image]

My question is: How can I click this button using VBA?

Comment: Is there an URL you can share? Anyway we can replicate this process? And what is o in the above? And what references are required to enable IUIAutomationCondition ?

Comment: It can be any URL when the Frame Notification Bar appears, e.g. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GE/history?p=GE. You have to click 'Download Data' button that is below 'Apply' button. I corrected the code and now definitions of each variable is given. 'UIAutomationClient' reference is needed.

Comment: Are you using something similar to this? I would simply use the download URL directly via binary download. For the link you supply there is an URL: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GE?period1=1536404905&period2=1538996905&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=QSTawVcqW3v  Then there are no notifications to deal with.

Comment: This is very nice solution. Thank you for this. Unfortunately, for the webpage that I use it is not possible to apply this solution, because there is no URL thanks to which the file can be saved.

Comment: Is there a way to get to something like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.close?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to apply this solution in VBA.

Comment: I've given a different, easier, solution below.

Comment: @MathMen Take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43969543/2165759).

Answer (score 0):

So I got this to work using the following .

Put the following at the top of the module as usual

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Public Const WM_DESTROY = &H2
Public Const WM_CLOSE = &H10
```

Put this after InvokePattern.Invoke, I put the time value there to be safe, may not be necessary.

```
  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
  SendMessage h, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace "Save" with "Close". So this part of the code will look like this

```
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Close")
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd) 
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke
```

Comment: You should edit your code to include a check to see if `e.FindFirst` succeeded or not, just-in-case the `"Close"` button isn't available. You also need to check if the button is enabled or not.

Comment: It's the educational answer - exactly to the question.