# Regex - matching html element with child elements on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, regex, node.js

I have a simple piece of HTML code.

```
<tr>
OtherElement
</tr>
<tr>
HelloWorld
</tr>
```

I need to match the `<tr></tr>` element containing HelloWorld.
I am using this regular expression but it matches first element as well.

```
<tr[\s\S]*?HelloWorld[\s\S]*?<\/tr>
```

I am using Node.js so I can not use look behind.

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/616443

Comment: Do you really need (_melius abundare quam deficere_) to parse **broken HTML** with regexes? Oh and where multiple lines on child elements are?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you receive the HTML fragment as a string. So, you need to parse it with DOM parser (after replacing all `tr` tags with another custom name since otherwise parsing will fail) and get only those `tr` elements that contain (not are equal to) the string `HelloWorld`.

```js
var $txt = "<tr>\nOtherElement\n</tr>\n<tr>Initial text\nHelloWorld\nSome other text</tr>";
var $el = document.createElement( 'body' );
$el.innerHTML = $txt.replace(/<(\/?)tr\b([^<]*)>/g, "<$1tablerows$2>"); // normalize TR tags as tablerows tags
var $arr = [];
[].forEach.call($el.getElementsByTagName("tablerows"), function(v,i,a) {
    if (v.innerText.indexOf("HelloWorld") > -1) {
  $arr.push(v.innerText);
    }
});
document.write(JSON.stringify($arr, 0, 4));
```

A regex solution is nasty and fragile, but possible:

```
<tr\b[^<]*>[^<]*(?:<(?!tr\b)[^<]*)*HelloWorld[^<]*(?:<(?!\/tr>)[^<]*)*<\/tr>
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gY1nI4/1)

The regex uses an unroll the loop technique to match the closest subpatterns.

- `<tr\b[^<]*>` - matches an opening TR tag
- `[^<]*(?:<(?!tr\b)[^<]*)*` - matches anything but `<tr` up to the
- `HelloWorld` - literal sequence
- `[^<]*(?:<(?!\/tr>)[^<]*)*` - all but closing `</tr>`
- `<\/tr>` - closing TR tag

Comment: I am using node.js so I can not use DOM parser, but your regex solution works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7373003/3832970) is still relevant, but it says you can use the [npm](http://npmjs.org/) modules [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsdom) and [htmlparser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/htmlparser) to create and parse a DOM in Node.JS.

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your regular expression. This character set is too permissive: `[\s\S]*?`

Try the following:

`<tr>\s*HelloWorld\s*<\/tr>`

`\s*` means 0 or more whitespace characters and nothing else.

And you may want to examine why you're using RegEx to parse HTML. This can be a useful approach for working with string snippets of known HTML, such as from a database, but in JavaScript you're probably better off using an XML parser or the DOM query selector methods.

Comment: How is `[\s]` different from `\s`?

Comment: @torazaburo it's not... That's what I get for modifying somebody else's RegEx instead of starting from scratch! Thanks for the correction, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse HTML with regexps. Instead, use DOM routines and properties:

```
function find_hello_world() {
  var trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

  for (var i=0; i<trs.length; i++) 
    if (trs[i].textContent === "HelloWorld") return trs[i];

}
```

Comment: I can not use DOM since I am not in the browser but in Node.js environment.