# Filtering and parsing from html string in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I have an HTML string and I need to find all  tags in that. Please suggest how to do in node js environment.

Comment: I need to find img tags in that html string.

Comment: Try [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) - it's like jQuery for Node :-)

Comment: You can use the npm modules jsdom and htmlparser to create and parse a DOM in Node.JS http://stackoverflow.com/a/7373003/5528611