# Parsing raw HTML to extract information with reactJS and NextJS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, next.js

I have an API that returns to me raw html. I want to extract some specific information. I was using Jquery in the past to do so :

```js
fetch(url)
    .then((html) => {
       const parsed = $(html)
       return parsed.find(id).attr('src')
    })
```

something like that.

Now that I moved to NextJs, I want to do this operation at compile time to do server rendering. In this function:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const data = await getData(params.slug)
    return { props: { data } }
}
```

I encountered a first problem where `jquery` needs a `window`.
I solved it by using this code:

```js
const jsdom = require('jsdom')
const $ = require('jquery')(new jsdom.JSDOM().window)
```

For someone that is encountering this problem too, I first had to resolve a module missing: `canvas`. I solved this by adding:

```
webpack: (config, { webpack }) => {
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/canvas/, /jsdom$/))
    return config
},
```

to my `next.config.js`.

But now I have a problem when I do: `$(html)`, it says that `$ is not a function`.

I tried this:

```js
const jsdom = require('jsdom')
const window = new jsdom.JSDOM().window
window.document.body.innerHTML = html
const parsed = require('jquery')(window)

parsed.find(id).attr('src')
```

but now I get `parsed.find(id).attr is not a function`.

Anyone could help ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a HTML page with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372972/how-do-i-parse-a-html-page-with-node-js)

Comment: Hello @juliomalves , it does not because I am using Netlify so I don't have access to server side code. Only the pre-rendered method from NextJS

Comment: `getStaticProps` runs on the server in a Node.js environment.