# How to use regex to convert HTML-wrapped markdown code blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

## Problem

I have files which have markdown code blocks, which, when exported, are surrounded by HTML `<p>` tags. For example, the code block

````
```python
def fn():
  pass
```                                              # comment added for formatting
````

Is exported as ```` <p>```python</p><p>def fn():</p><p> pass</p><p>```</p> ````

What I want is to convert these to HTML code blocks using JavaScript (I'm currently working in Google Apps Script, but can use Node.js if necessary).

For example, the string directly above should be converted to `<pre><code language=python>def fn():\n   pass</code><pre>`

What is the best way to go about doing this?

## Attempted solutions

I first attempted to use a regex to capture the language and lines of code separately, after which I would then use `String.replace()` to format, but I was not able to write a suitable regex.

I'm currently using this regex: ```` /<p>```((?:\w)*)<\/p>(?:<p>((?:.)*?)<\/p>)<p>```<\/p>/g ````. Which captures the language and then all code lines (still with tags). For example, run on the above code block it returns `python` in a first capture group, and `def fn():</p><p>  pass` in a second.

I then tried to use `String.replace(regex, replacement)`, where `replacement` was somehow a function of the second capture group (in order to remove the `<p>` tags), but that did not work.

Currently, the best thing I can think of is to iterate over every match and replace that substring by index:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(start, end, replacement) {
    return this.substring(0, start) + replacement + this.substring(end);
}

  var replacedText = inputText
  while(null != (z=backtickRegex.exec(inputText))) {
    var newString = `<pre><code language=${z[1]}>${z[2].replaceAll('</p><p>', '\n')}</code></pre>`
    replacedText = replacedText.replaceAt(z.index, z.index+z[0].length, newString)
  }
```

However, this feels **incredibly inelegant**.

**Is there a better way to do this that I am missing? Any insight is much appreciated!**

Comment: Generally use a DOM parser to parse and extract data from html, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372972/how-do-i-parse-a-html-page-with-node-js

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just going with this:

````js
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(start, end, replacement) {
    return this.substring(0, start) + replacement + this.substring(end);
}

// helper to turn markdown code blocks to html
function codeBlocksToHTML(inputText) {
  // This regex captures the language in a first group, and then the code WITH P TAGS in a second
  const backtickRegex = /<p>```((?:\w)*)<\/p>(?:<p>((?:.)*?)<\/p>)<p>```<\/p>/g;
  
  // for every match, remove the code p tags
  while(null != (z=backtickRegex.exec(inputText))) {
    var newString = `<pre><code language=${z[1]}>${z[2].replaceAll('</p><p>', '\n')}</code></pre>`
    inputText = inputText.replaceAt(z.index, z.index+z[0].length, newString)  
  }

  return inputText;
}
````

Good enough I think