# How to remove trailing slash from URL in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, url

I want to remove any trailing slash from URL that can be found on HTML files with Node.js.

I know that there are `rewrite` or `redirect` rule for NGINX that I use for serving my site, but I really want to do this too. I want to remove those pesky trailing slash from my site, once and for all. Those `rewrite` or `redirect` is not enough.

I can't configure Hugo that I use for generating my site to not add trailing slash to URL. I have to either use `https://example.com/b/content/article-01.html` or `https://example.com/b/content/article-01/` and I don't like both. I want `https://example.com/b/content/article-01`.

If Hugo won't allow me to use *clean* URL, I'll just post-process the generated site myself.

---

Here are what I've found to define URL in the content of HTML files.

- The URL is after either `href=`, `href="`, `content=`, `content="`.
- The URL is before `"` (only if it is after `href="` or `content="`) or  (space) or `>`.
- The URL starts with either `http` or `/`.
- Do not remove slash if the URL is exactly `/`.

So, these are URLs that I have to process.

- `http://example.com/` -> `http://example.com`
- `https://example.com/` -> `https://example.com`
- `/b/content/article-01/` -> `/b/content/article-01`
- `https://example.com/b/content/article-01/` -> `https://example.com/b/content/article-01`
- `/` -> `/`

I've managed to code this for removing trailing slash from content of files, but I don't know what to use for HTML file.

```js
function removeTrailingSlash(dirPath) {
  const files = glob.sync(`${dirPath}/**/*.+(html|xml)`)
  const regexHTML = // How?
  const regexXML = /<(?:link|guid|loc)>(https?:\/\/[^<]+)<\/(?:link|guid|loc)>/g // XML part is fine

  function rts(url) {
    if (url.length > 1 && url.endsWith('/')) {
      return url.slice(0, -1)
    }
    return url
  }

  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file)
    let content = readFileSync(file, 'utf8')
    if (file.endsWith('.html')) {
      content = content.replace(regexHTML, (match, url) => {
        return match.replace(url, rts(url))
      })
    } else if (file.endsWith('.xml')) {
      content = content.replace(regexXML, (match, url) => {
        return match.replace(url, rts(url))
      })
    }
    writeFileSync(file, content)
  })
}
```

How can I remove trailing slash from the content of the HTML file?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to manipulate HTML. See the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: That's why I limited definition of 'What is URL' in the question. There is no 'one for all' regex for finding URL in HTML, so I limited the condition. With it, it should be possible to find and replace 'URL'. If there is any other better way to remove trailing slash from the URL, I'll use it gladly.

Comment: It is not enough case but it may help you `(http|https):\/\/.+\/` and `(href|content)="?\/\S+\/`

Comment: There are packages out there like [JSDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom), [LinkeDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkedom) and a lot more which allow parsing html files from within NodeJS and give you the possibilty to use functions like `querySelectorAll()` and alter the content. So you can use `document.querySelectorAll("[href],[content]")` to get all elements matching your search pattern, then alter the strings based on your needs and store the altered HTML afterwards. See also [How do I parse a HTML page with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7372972/10304804).

Comment: @davi FYI "first" answer depends on user's *sorted by* - you can link directly to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2181514)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already used a parser to extract a string from your `href` or `content` attributes...

```
((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^?#\s\'\"]+))\/([?#\s\'\"]|$)
```

This approach looks for

| Regex Portion | Interpretation |
| --- | --- |
| ( | Start of capture group 1 |
| (?:https?:\/\/)? | "http://", "https://", or "" |
| (?:[^?#\s'"]+) | One or more characters that don't terminate a path |
| ) | End of capture group 1 |
| / | A slash character |
| ([?#\s\'\"]|$) | Capture group 2 holding any character that terminates a path |

In code, you'd replace the entire match with the two capture groups.  You could alter the regex to include your attribute names as a simple prefix inside capture group 1 if you were to approach the problem without a parser.