# Adding fixtures to jasmine/ Setting up Jasmine-Jquery

Tags: javascript, tdd, coffeescript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to use the jasmine-jquery plugin: https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery.  In the documentation it says to:

> Simply download jasmine-jquery.js from the downloads page and include
>   it in your Jasmine's test runner file (or add it to jasmine.yml file
>   if you're using Ruby with jasmine-gem). Remember to include also
>   jQuery library as jasmine-jquery relies on it.

I'm trying to use this plugin to add fixtures to my jasmine tests in coffeescript for a coffeescript one page HTML5 canvas application.  I'm using the jasmine-node version of jasmine to run my jasmine tests using node.js  My issue with the above instructions is that I do not see a jasmine test runner file to edit, and as a result I'm unable to call methods from this plugin such as load_fixtures in my specs.

My current directory structure for the project is

```
coffescript/shape.coffee
index.html (An html file I would ideally like to use for my tests)
javascript/shape.js (The outputted coffeescript)
spec/shape.spec.coffee
spec/jasmine-jquery-1.3.1.js (The plugin)
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated as I've spent several hours trying to get this to work correctly.  If you know a different test framework with fixtures that would be easier to setup for a coffeescript project that was also be welecomed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library you are trying to use assumes that you are using jasmine in a html page. Neither it nor jquery will work with jasmine-node.

jQuery cannot work on node because it needs the browser's DOM api. There are some [libraries that mock the DOM for node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js) that might give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The test runner file you refer to is included in the standalone version of Jasmine (SpecRunner.html). It is not part of Jasmine-node.