# HTML-parser on Node.js

Tags: html, parsing, node.js, nokogiri

Is there something like Ruby's [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) on nodejs?
I mean a user-friendly HTML-parser.

I'd seen on Node.js modules page some parsers, but I can't find something pretty and fresh.

Comment: What do you mean by "friendly"? Convenient to work and select nodes with, like Nokogiri's XPath and CSS selector support? Amenable to parsing invalid "tag soup" HTML?

Comment: If you are comfortable with jQuery, consider [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31361044/778272).

Answer (score 464, accepted):

If you want to build [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) you can use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

There's also [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio), it has the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) interface and it's a lot faster than older versions of jsdom, although these days they are similar in performance.

You might wanna have a look at [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2), which is a streaming parser, and according to its benchmark, it seems to be faster than others, and no DOM by default. It can also produce a DOM, as it is also bundled with a handler that creates a DOM. This is the parser that is used by cheerio.

[parse5](https://github.com/inikulin/parse5) also looks like a good solution. It's fairly active (11 days since the last commit as of this update), WHATWG-compliant, and is used in [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular), and [Polymer](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer).

If the website you're trying to scrape is [dynamic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page) then you should be using a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). Also have a look at [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/), if you're considering phantomjs. And you can control casperjs from node with [SpookyJS](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS).

Beside phantomjs there's [zombiejs](http://zombie.labnotes.org/). Unlike phantomjs that cannot be embedded in nodejs, zombiejs is just a node module.

There's a [nettuts+ toturial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/web-scraping-with-node-js/) for the latter solutions.

Comment: You can get DOM from htmlparser2 using DomHandler module (bundled with htmlparser2). They are separated on purpose to allow for other kinds of processing HTML without overhead of creating DOM.

Comment: @esp Thanks, Before I thought it was non-standard DOM, I changed that section accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure how you YQL for crawling - it's more for joining web service results not processing markup.

Comment: @dardenfall You are right, crawling is not the right term. I changed it with scraping :)

Comment: @Farid - (would've just messaged you if I could) at the risk of debating in comments (sorry!) I still don't see how you use it for scraping.  It works with web _services_ not sites, and with wservices, you're rarely parsing html.  Maybe xml, but not html.

Comment: Well it's like YQL(the webservice) does the hard work(fetching and parsing) for you. For example you want to find some stackoverflow questions: You can either use cheerio and request: `request('stackoverflow.com', function (err, body) { console.log(cheerio.load(body)('.question-hyperlink')) };` or use YQL: `yql('select * from data.html.cssselect where url="stackoverflow.com" and css=".question-hyperlink"', function (err, results) { console.log(results); })`. The latter will use way less of your system resources.

Answer (score 15):

Try https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom - you give it some HTML and it gives you a DOM.

Answer (score 6):

You can also take a look at x-ray: https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray