# Extract image src from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm trying to match all the images elements as strings,

This is my regex:

```
html.match(/<img[^>]+src="http([^">]+)/g);
```

This works, but I want to extract the `src` of all the images. So when I execute the regular expression on this String:

`<img src="http://static2.ccn.com/ccs/2013/02/img_example.jpg />`

it returns:

`"http://static2.ccn.com/ccs/2013/02/img_example.jpg"`

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html.

Comment: I have to do with regex

Comment: @Tomirammstein, why do you have to do it with a regex when Javascript has DOM built in?

Comment: @Tomirammstein In which environment is your JavaScript code executing? If it's a web-browsers, just parse the HTML string into a DOM tree.

Comment: Too bad... with JQuery it would be     `$('img[src="http://static2.ccn.com/ccs"]').each(function(){});`

Comment: @dan1111 Not exactly. JavaScript is just a scripting language. The DOM is not built-in in *web-browsers*, not JavaScript.

Comment: I'm using node.js, so, I can't parse it into an HTML tree

Comment: https://github.com/harryf/node-soupselect maybe this could help

Comment: @Tomirammstein Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977945/html-parser-on-nodejs

Comment: @Tomirammstein Don't you think it would've been helpful to tag this question as `node.js` in the first place?

Comment: Don't you think that node.js it's based on Javscript?

Comment: Yes but they aren't the same. You said it yourself, node.js is **based** on Javascript - it doesn't include everything and isn't perfectly identical. I'm just saying, tagging it correctly and explaining it better could've helped get a more direct and correct solution, faster.

Comment: this regx is not working incase we have entire html as a string and i want to find out the image url out of it. Anyone can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57883657/find-if-content-has-current-website-url-in-javascript

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to use a capture group `()` to extract the urls, and if you're wanting to match globally `g`, i.e. more than once, when using capture groups, you need to use `exec` in a loop (`match` ignores capture groups when matching globally).

For example

```
var m,
    urls = [], 
    str = '<img src="http://site.org/one.jpg />\n <img src="http://site.org/two.jpg />',
    rex = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\/>/g;

while ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) {
    urls.push( m[1] );
}

console.log( urls ); 
// [ "http://site.org/one.jpg", "http://site.org/two.jpg" ]
```

Comment: Ended up with this instead. Otherwise, it doesn't pick up all images. /<img[^>]+src="([^">]+)/g

Comment: some times img tag may have height or some other attr after "src" attr.So regex should be rex = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?[^>]*\/>/g;

Comment: seems that this regex not works on all img tags, but this works /<img.*?src="([^">]*\/([^">]*?))".*?>/g;

Comment: this regx is not working incase we have entire html as a string and i want to find out the image url out of it. Can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57883657/find-if-content-has-current-website-url-in-javascript

Answer (score 8):

```
var myRegex = /<img[^>]+src="(http:\/\/[^">]+)"/g;
var test = '<img src="http://static2.ccn.com/ccs/2013/02/CC_1935770_challenge_accepted_pack_x3_indivisible.jpg" />';
myRegex.exec(test);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me. I just want to add this: `var src = myRegex.exec(test); console.log('SRC: ' + src[1]);`

Comment: this regx is not working incase we have entire html as a string and i want to find out the image url out of it. Can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57883657/find-if-content-has-current-website-url-in-javascript

Answer (score 7):

As Mathletics mentioned in a comment, there are other more straightforward ways to retrieve the *src* attribute from your `<img>` tags such as retrieving a reference to the DOM node via id, name, class, etc. and then just using your reference to extract the information you need. If you need to do this for all of your `<img>` elements, you can do something like this:

```
var imageTags = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); // Returns array of <img> DOM nodes
var sources = [];
for (var i in imageTags) {
   var src = imageTags[i].src;
   sources.push(src);
}
```

However, if you have some restriction forcing you to use regex, then the other answers provided will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

What I did is slightly modified your regex then used the `exec` function to get array of matched strings. if you have more then 1 match the other matches will be on `results[2]`, `results[3]`...

```
var html = '<img src="http://static2.ccn.com/ccs/2013/02/CC_1935770_challenge_accepted_pack_x3_indivisible.jpg" />';

var re = /<img[^>]+src="http:\/\/([^">]+)/g
var results = re.exec(html);

var source = results[1];
alert(source);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an html parser and avoid regexp at all.

```
var parser = require('node-html-parser');

var html = '<img src="http://static2.ccn.com/ccs/2013/02/CC_1935770_challenge_accepted_pack_x3_indivisible.jpg" />'

parser.parse(html).querySelector('img').getAttribute('src')

=> 'http://static2.ccn.com/ccs/2013/02/CC_1935770_challenge_accepted_pack_x3_indivisible.jpg'
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the `src` value using **groups**

```
                                                   |->captured in group 1
                                   ----------------------------------                
var yourRegex=/<img[^>]+src\s*=\s*"(http://static2.ccn.com/ccs[^">]+)/g;
var match = yourRegex.exec(yourString);
alert(match[1]);//src value
```