# Extract page content and image using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am getting page content using:

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
```

Now I want to extract

1. image and
2. data part leaving script and html code.

This is regex for image I used:

```
function get_logo($data) 
{
    return preg_match("/<img(.*?)src=(\"|\')(.+?)(gif|jpg|png|bmp)(\"|\')(.*?)(\/)?>(<\/img>)?/", $html, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';
}
```

which returns nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that `preg_match` is javascript?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for HTML parsing.

Comment: @jerry: it's php function

Comment: Check this question!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939296/extract-image-src-from-a-string

Maybe this can help you! :)

Comment: @Karimkhan You should tag your questions appropriately. If you are using PHP, don't tag your question as javascript unless javascript is also involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will extract image urls from $data variable:

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src=([\'"])([^"\']+)\1/i', $content, $matches);
var_dump($matches[2]);
```

In in array $matches[2] will be all links to images from the $content

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML!

I would suggest you to use a HTML DOM parse like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

1) We don't see html and it is difficult understand that you need.

2) `preg_match_all("/<img[^>]+src=[\"|\'](.+\.(gif|jpg|png|bmp))[\"|\']/im", $html, $matches)` return all img tags, image names and extensions on page