# Split json image and text from string

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, split

I'm struggling to seperate **image** from **text**. I converted rss feed to json, because its easier to work whit, but I don't know how to split string or seperate image form text.

**JSON:**  `"description": "<img src=\"https://files.facepunch.com/s/cd60c1258ac2.jpg\"><br/>Raids, bases, mods, and more.",`

***Trying to get only*** `<img src=\"https://files.facepunch.com/s/cd60c1258ac2.jpg\">`

I'm begginer and started learning javascript recently, but can't figure out how if is even possible to split this.

> https://jsfiddle.net/4szqst2m/

Comment: Try something first and show us your code

Comment: Added example from my code, still don't know if is possible to split/extract image from string under "description" property

Comment: You need to json decode the string, then you will be able to access the description as an array.

Comment: Still no clue how to solve this problem @JimWright how do you mean decode?

Comment: Please read up on parsing JSON with the `JSON.parse` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course depending on the text you pass this how you do it using `regex`:

```js
var json = " \"description\": \"<img src=\"https://files.facepunch.com/s/cd60c1258ac2.jpg\"><br/>Raids, bases, mods, and more.";

var rex = /(<img[^>]+src="?[^"\s]+"?\s*\/?>)/g;

var imgTag = ''; 
var m = '';

while (m = rex.exec(json) ) {
    imgTag = m[1];
}

alert(imgTag);
```

[Take a look at this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939296/extract-image-src-from-a-string)