# Find if content has current website url in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE as an editor. I want to perform validation mobile and URL validation.

What is not allowed ?

1. Mobile number is not allowed to enter on description.
2. Only same application urls are allowed to enter on description box. If user enters other website urls should throw a validation error.

I have used below code to validate mobile and url but the moment I upload image using TinyMCE editor, the html content consists of image tag which has a url of image. Image is uploaded in the application.

As i have done url validation, system is not allowing me to proceed.

Case 1: If you check, "myText" variable holds a string which has 1 image tag, mobile number, different website url (google.com). - Validation Error.

Case 2: Now if I delete mobile number but keep google.com in the given input - Validation Error.

Case 3. Any website url other than my application url - Validation Error.

Case 4: No Mobile number, No Other Website Url but Image url is the same application url (example.com) - Validation Passed.

Check "currentDomainUrl".

```js
    function hasURL(str) {
      var res = str.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);

      return (res !== null);
    }

 $('#btnClick').click(function() {

    const PATTERN_MOBILE_INDIA = /\b([0|+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})\b/;
    var myText = '<p><img src="https://example.com/images/image_1568090359_myimg.jpg" alt="" width="564" height="290" /></p><p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don t look even slightly believable.</p><p>9524026761</p><p>Website: https://google.com/</p><p>If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>';
    var match = myText.match(PATTERN_MOBILE_INDIA);
    var contains = match != null;
    var hasUrl = hasURL(myText);
    var currentDomainUrl = ['https://example.com/', 'http://example.com/',
    'example.com'];

    if (contains || hasUrl) {
      // Check If "myText" have any image url or any url in content as the 
       // same url of current website url then no error will be thrown.
       // validation error
       alert('mobile number and url in content not allowed!');
       return false;
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button id="btnClick">Check Validation</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your questio is not clear: do you want to accept just urls with the same base-url or do you also want to accept (only india?) mobile number?

Comment: @Meziane Validation Error On: 1. If user type Mobile number on description. 2. Different website url are not allowed. User can add only current application's urls.  Is this clear ?

Comment: @Meziane I have added more information. Please check and help on this.

Comment: Your problem is also just to accept urls with the same base-url as your site's url. What have mobile numbers to do here?
Just check the entered url and reject it, if its base-url is not like the site's one.

Comment: Yes, accepting url as base url only. Other url should not be entertained. And also mobile number is not allowed to enter. I have done mobile and url validation but facing issue on checking base url exists in variable "myText". I am beginner in regular expression. code is provided as above. Can you help on this ?

Comment: Why are you speaking about mobile numbers?
You just have to check if the entered url is conform.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199321/discussion-between-appsntech-and-meziane).

Comment: I am lying sick in bed. I can help you tomorrow.

Comment: Sure, will appreciate your help. thank you.