# How to get content of <img src=> from body

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I have a link for Tumblr API that gives the tagged posts with the given tag(`https://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?api_key=blablabla&tag=red`)

[This](https://ibb.co/grSh95D) the response from the request.

I want to just get the content of the `<img src =>` , I want just the links inside, when I make a get request it loads the whole thing, I've tried puppeteer, fetch, `document.getelementbyId("node js is screaming")`, miserably failed..

How can I get just the links inside the `<img src>`

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a code writing service. There is plenty of information on how to scrape a website on Google. Pick an implementation, try it, and if you need help, come back and show us your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract image src from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939296/extract-image-src-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the response then scan it with a `regex` for `img` tags.

Example:

```js
var response = 'your code response here'
var regex = /<img(.*?)>/g;
var imgtags = response.match(regex);
console.log(imgtags //);`
```

Now, `imgtags` contain all tags which start with "img", and you can use any arbitrary logic (including another custom `regex`) to select the one(s) you need.