# finding html element in jquery string

Tags: jquery

I have this code where I am trying to find number of elements in a string using jquery,

```
var s = 'assasdsa<img src="http://localhost/cc/public/img/smileys/flushed face.png">sdsdajjk';  
var k = $(s).find('*'); 
console.log(k.length);
```

It gives an error though,

```
jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: assasdsa<img src="http://localhost/cc/public/img/smileys/flushed face.png">sdsdajjk
```

Comment: s is not an html syntax, so the error is normal...so you cant use jquery to find selector

Comment: @Frenchy how can I find that img element in string ?

Comment: you use regexp to search something which is inside < and >

Comment: This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939296/extract-image-src-from-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the string to an element and find within that element instead

```js
var s = 'assasdsa<img src="http://localhost/cc/public/img/smileys/flushed face.png">sdsdajjk';  
var k = $('<div>').append(s).find('*'); 
console.log(k.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how does it work ? and what was wrong with my code ?

Comment: *how does it work* - same as you attempted, but jquery needs a "root" html element - in this case `<div>` you could just as easily do `$("<div>" + your_string + "</div>")` - but your_string doesn't have a root, so won't parse correctly