# Get encoded content from javascript object and display it on pug, how?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, pug, javascript-objects

I got an XML which contained tag `<content:encoded>` which I have processed to this form.
There are several tag and I am currently struggle at this particular tag.
Example :

```
{
  title: [
    'the title goes here'
  ],
  link: [
    'https://anotherlink.com'
  ],
  description: [
    '<img src="https://something.com/foo.jpg"/>Some words here'
  ],
  'content:encoded': [
    'This content is what I want to get, also with escaped characters included'
  ],
  guid: [
    'https://something.com'
  ]
}
```

my pug page:

```
extends mp

block layout-content
  div.View
    h1.Banner Hello!
    data_in
    ul
      each element in data_in
          li
            div.Message
              div.Title
                h1= element.title                  >this gets expected output
                h3= element.content|encoded        >this gets wrong output
```

How do I get that encoded content , while with the same code do well when I getting the 'title' attribute ? Do I have to do another iteration ?
Thank you

*edit : I mean , 'title' **value**

Comment: Can you clarify what "wrong output" is? Have you tried `h3= element['content:encoded']`?

Comment: The wrong output was "0" , just plain text "0" . But your solution works ! Thank you ! That doesn't cross me. This is out of topic, usually there's some attributes like <img src = "something.com" /> How can I get the "something.com" ?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939296/extract-image-src-from-a-string