# Node.js document is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why node.js does not recognize document.GetElementById? 
It says 'ReferenceError: document is not defined'.
What can I do?

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\main.js:9:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: because... node.js doesn't have DOM like the browser does built-in.

Comment: @KevinB: can you post that answer so it can be accepted, please? Thanks.

Comment: @Felix Remus already has.

Comment: Considering the fact you are trying to get a value based on ID and I'm just trying to do the same, this answer might be of much greater use to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977945/html-parser-on-node-js

Comment: try `window.document.getElementById` instead

Comment: @Jacksonkr Node also doesn’t have a `window`. Why should one “try” that?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Please excuse me, ReactJS was on the brain. You are absolutely correct: out of the box `node` has no idea what `document` nor `window` are. If you are using node with `commonJS` or some sort of browser-friendly environment you may need to listen for some sort of dom-loaded event before accessing global browser objects. Depending on your situation a cheap trick may be to add a `try catch`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document) relates to the DOM (Document Object Model) in a web browser.

Node.js, however, is not a browser environment. It is a server environment, much like PHP or Perl, and as such, you can’t access the browser’s DOM or do anything specific to browser-hosted JavaScript.

The closest you could get is using something like [browserify](/questions/tagged/browserify) to include Node.js modules in your client-side code.

Comment: Can you point me to some code that uses `browserify` that does exactly this?

Comment: Nope, but they've got [docs](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage). Keep in mind, the behaviour of a client app (DOM-accessible) is massively different from a server app. You won't be able to start up a server or do any server-related activities in the browser with browserify; it's mostly for taking cleanly-packaged NPM modules (e.g. Moment.js or Lodash) and making them available.

Comment: I find this answer could be of much more use if you were to provide cases where we NEED to emulate the browser dom server side for certain libraries such as pdf.js.

Comment: Sure, but that wasn't what the question was about. Ask a new one if you need to.

Comment: And webpack. And esbuild. And parcel. And rollup.

Comment: https://browserify.org/

Answer (score 58):

You could use [JSDom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to add Dom support to Node. To make a variable global you can use either

```
GLOBAL.document = new JSDOM(html).window.document;
```

or

```
global.document = new JSDOM(html).window.document;
```

where `html` is your website as a string.

To use JSDom include it in your project with:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
```

or in plain js with:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var JSDOM = jsdom.JSDOM;
```

I hope this is answering your question.

Answer (score 17):

To understand the answer, it's necessary to know the relationship of: **Javascript Engine**, **Browser** and **Node.js**.

**Javascript Engine**: is Javascript compiler which turns JS into machine code. For example, **V8**, is a great one. Technically V8 is developed in C++ (you can regard it as a C++ program).

V8 implements **ECMAScript**, which is a standard of Javascript language defining the features and functionalities of JavaScript.

But **DOM** operation is not defined by ECMAScript. So V8 doesn't support it.

**Browser**: And developers can use `document` for DOM operation in browser, because DOM operation is provided by browser, for example: Chrome.

Chrome is also developed by C++ and V8(as mentioned abvoe, which is developed by C++ as well) is embedded into Chrome to interpret Javascript. So Chrome expends or adds features to Javascript by binding JS command and C++ implementation together.

**Nodejs**: different from the Chrome, it is a server side program. But the same thing is that Nodejs is developed by C++ and V8 is embedded into Nodejs to handle js. Nodejs expands features of Javascript in the similar way with Chrome. But since server side doesn't need to handle DOM, so you can not access such functions inside Nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string) just add this comment to the top of your *.test.js* file to configure your environment:

```
/**
* @jest-environment jsdom
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in React make sure u properly use JSX elements and render without document element. If you need to use document then use

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
here u can use document. element
}

but u cannot use it to render inside because in React conditional render doesn't work

u can use instead:

```
import Register from './Register'
import { Box, Center } from '@chakra-ui/react'
function App() {
    return (
        <main>
            <Box>
                <Register />
            </Box>
        </main>
    )
}

export default App
```

where Register is example of element you want to render

Answer (score -6):

OK, shorter answer is you wanna access `document` Object which is only available in the window and front end side, don't forget that `document` === `window.document` which you don't have access in the server and node side...

So never try something like this on your node side for example getting root element by ID which will throw the error, instead try to access it from FrontEnd:

```
document.getElementById('root');
```

will throw an Error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\app.js:12:50)
at Module._compile (my.js:490:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (my.js:518:10)
at Module.load (my.js:555:42)
at Function.Module._load (my.js:610:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (my.js:701:10)
at startup (node.js:899:16)
at node.js:901:3
```

The short answer is don't use **document** and **window** object in `node.js` as they are not available in `node.js`...

Using **Domino** could help in some cases for accessing the dom...

> As the name might suggest, domino's goal is to provide a DOM in Node.
>
> In contrast to the original dom.js project, domino was not designed to
>   run untrusted code. Hence it doesn't have to hide its internals behind
>   a proxy facade which makes the code not only simpler, but also more
>   performant.
>
> Domino currently doesn't use any harmony features like proxies or
>   WeakMaps and therefore also runs in older Node versions.

For more info, visit [here](https://github.com/fgnass/domino)...

Comment: This answered nothing

Comment: This restates the problem. It does not answer it

Answer (score -22):

- "`npm install npm -g`"
- after that "`npm install -g typescript`"

this command helped me for this problem