# Create HTML file by using HTML DOM methods and write into that HTML file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to write HTML file in nodejs. I need to create elements using all the DOM methods. I tried following, but throwing error `document is undefined`. Please suggest me what wrong I am doing and what is the right way to do this. Thanks

```
var fs     = require('fs');

var myDiv= document.createElement("div");
myDiv.setAttribute("id","myDiv");'

var data = myDiv.outerHTML;

var writerStream = fs.createWriteStream('abcd.html');
writerStream.write(data,'UTF8');
writerStream.end();
writerStream.on('finish', function() {    console.log("Write completed."); });
writerStream.on('error', function(err){   console.log(err.stack); }); 
console.log("Program Ended");
```

Comment: for why its not defined in nodejs look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined

Comment: Yeah I look into it. but it is pointing out the issue. Not telling how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to there is no window object available. Remember document object comes from window.
When we write document, it is actually window.document. 
But nodejs does not provide the window object, as it runs on serverside.

So to do this you can use a module called **jsdom**.  Go through jsdom here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jsdom

Install jsdom  and try something like:

```
var jsdom  = require('jsdom');
var fs     = require('fs');
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
     response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
     response.end('Hello World\n'); 
}).listen(8081); 
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');

jsdom.env({
  html: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/',
  src: [],
  done: function(errors, window) {

    var document = window.document;
    var myDiv= document.createElement("div");
    myDiv.setAttribute("id","myDiv");'

    var data = myDiv.outerHTML;

    var writerStream = fs.createWriteStream('abcd.html');
    writerStream.write(data,'UTF8');
    writerStream.end();
    writerStream.on('finish', function() {    console.log("Write completed."); });
    writerStream.on('error', function(err){   console.log(err.stack); }); 
    console.log("Program Ended");

  }
});
```

Comment: how to install jsdom

Comment: npm install node-jsdom

Comment: @Tuhin The OP asked a question which can be answered in multiple ways. *One* of them is "use jsdom". This does not warrant adding the tag to the question. So I've reverted your edit. It would have been okay if the OP had specifically asked a question *about jsdom* but that was not the case here.

Comment: Okay.. I will remove then