# how to access dom in npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a NPM package and I want to write something to the DOM inside my function. But I get an error saying the document is not defined
example,

foo package:

```
module.exports = {
    sayHello: function(){
        document.getElementByID('#hello').innerHTML('Hello');
    }
}
```

In client-side javascript:

```
import { sayHello } from 'foo';
$('#myButton').click(() => sayHello());
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a typo at

```
document.getElementByID
```

The correct spelling is

```
document.getElementById
```

Besides that the question may be a duplicate of 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined)