# How to select image name which is define in CSS Puppeteer/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, browser-automation

How can I select an image name which is defined in CSS?

I can select that CSS image class using JavaScript, but how can I get the image name inside that class? I want to to do it in Puppeteer/Node.js.

I want to click on this class given below if the image inside the class given below matches `paper.gif`.

CLASS:

```
.height-20 span a {
   background-image: url("paper.gif");
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

SELECTOR:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.height-20 span a'); // Select all Products but how to get image inside this selector?
```

CLICKER:

```
 await page.click(".height-20 span a");
```

What I want to achieve is given below:

```
if(css image == paper.gif) {
await page.click(".height-20 span a");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) obtained from [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to an array of Nodes, and then you can filter that array by elements that contain a [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) that equals `'paper.gif'`:

```
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.height-20 span a')].filter(e => {
  const background_image = window.getComputedStyle(e).backgroundImage.split('/').pop().replace(/[")]/g, '');
  return background_image === 'paper.gif';
});
```

This implementation can be placed inside [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args), and you can [`click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) the element from within that page DOM scope if an element exists that matches the given criteria:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.height-20 span a')].filter(e => {
    const background_image = window.getComputedStyle(e).backgroundImage.split('/').pop().replace(/[")]/g, '');
    return background_image === 'paper.gif';
  });

  if (elements.length) {
    elements[0].click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try and will get back to you. I will accept the answer if it worked for me.

Comment: I tried your code but I am getting an error 

(node:6571) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: document is not defined. So I checked it out 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined

Comment: @SayedMohdAli It sounds like you might be trying to initialize `elements` without placing it in `page.evaluate()`. The page DOM environment contains the `document` object, but the Node.js environment does not.

Comment: ok, bro, I will check it out in my code again and will rate you positively if worked. thanks for your time

Comment: I am getting any error now, NodeJS is also working but the click is not working at all. Is there anything to do with the link of the background image?

return background_image === 'https://www.example.com/img/icon/a-syed-follow.png';

Answer (score 0):

@Grant Miller is correct, +1. I just wanted to provide a simple `getStyleFromElement` in **TypeScript**:

```js
export async function getStyleFromElement(page: Page, elementHandle: ElementHandle, cssProperty: string): Promise<string> {
  // page.evaluate evaluates the given function from inside the browser context
  // so elementHandle and cssProperty are not available in the scope of the function.
  // That is why we pass it. Puppeteer automatically converts the elementHandle
  // into the correct DOM element, though

  return page.evaluate((element, property) =>
    window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(property), elementHandle, cssProperty);
}
```

You can now get the `background-image` by calling:

> getStyleFromElement(page, element, "background-image");

And bonus, if you want to extract the URL from inside the `url(...)` construct:

```js
export function getUrlFromBackgroundImage(backgroundImage: string): string | null {
  if (!backgroundImage) return null;
  const match = backgroundImage.match(/url\("(.*)"\)/);
  if (match) {
    return match[1];
  }
  return null;
}
```