# I can't import Bootstrap in my NPM project

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to import bootstrap through the npm console, but I don't know how to connect the packages with my project.
I've tried to import it in my **index.mjs** like this: `import 'bootstrap'`, but the console drop me an error saying: `Reference error: document is not defined`. I'm using Handlebars engine.
Thanks!

Comment: Bootstrap is for browser environment only. Are you trying to output JavaScript (from Handlebars) that uses Bootstrap?

Comment: To wit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I suspect that the poster is trying to add bootstrap to a server-rendered page that used handlebars as its templating engine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you're trying to add bootstrap to a server-rendered page that uses handlebars as its templating engine.

Inside your server page, I'm going to call it `app.js` you should add the following two lines:

```
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')));
```

Then in your master page, and I'm going to call it `layout.hbs` you would add these references:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="./js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

Once you have those lines of code in those files, you should now have `bootstrap` and its accompanying JavaScript files ready for use by your HTML elements.

Good luck and hope this helps you out.

Comment: It was very useful! Thanks.