# ReferenceError: document is not defined when using document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, dom, referenceerror

code:

```
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require("C:/Users/santo/Downloads/bestmpos-firebase-adminsdk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

let fs = admin.firestore();
let auth = admin.auth();

start();
async function start (uid, userRecord){
  const info = await fs.collection('users').doc(uid).get();
 console.table(info.data());
 document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Bonjour";
}
```

Html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app3.js"></script>
    <body>
            <p id="greeting">Hello</p>
        </body>
```

when I wanted to pass `bonjour` value by using `getElementById()` there is a error saying that **document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Bonjour";
ReferenceError: document is not defined**

Comment: firebase-admin is meant to run on a node server, not the browser. Re check the documentation

Comment: This is usually caused by the code running before the page finishes rendering. Moving the script tag below the body should fix it

Comment: I just wanted to display the info from firebase to a HTML page

Comment: @Pandicon no, `document` *not existing* is usually caused by the code not running on a page at all but on Node.js

Comment: @Pandicon That would cause a different error (like not finding an element); `document` is available regardless of load status in a browser environment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined