# ReferenceError: document is not defined (JavaScript in VS Code)

Tags: javascript, dom, document

Im learning JS. Found a good video "JavaScript Programming - Full Course" and stucked at the 2nd part where I need to use DOM. I have the HTML document, in  i refered to the JS file. Other stuff working well, but this:

let messageEL = document.getElementById("message-el")

Always get this error:

ReferenceError: document is not defined

I installed live server, and it works one time, than stops.

What can I do, to fix this? Do I need to download some extension?
Please tell me the solution as simple as u can Im at the beginning of the learning path.

[This is the code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQJce.png)

Comment: node is to run JS only documents, outside a browser. Also please post code, not images of code (in general)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js document is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, you're attempting to run the script using Node.js (the server-side JavaScript executable).

Since you say you're running live-server, you should be looking at your browser instead, not trying to run your code via Node.

Comment: This is definitely a dupe

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined

Comment: @ChrisG That's indeed a dupe of the question, but the accepted top answer alludes to using browserify, which wouldn't help OP at all.