# How to export specific data from a Javascript file to Node.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, node-modules

```
// index.js
let intro = document.getElementById('intro');
let name = "Harry";
module.exports = name;
    
// new.js
let name = require("./index.js");
console.log(name);
```

I am trying to build an application with Node.js. When I want to export a string or specific data with module.exports to use it in the new.js file, an error is logged in the console saying that "document is not defined".
All I need is to export a variable having a string to my Node.js (new.js). Also my index.js have multiple document.getElements. I also noticed that when I remove document.getElements then I successfully import that data from index.js without any error. How could I export data from index.js file with that document.getElement present in that?

Comment: The global variable `document` exists in a web browser, but not in Node. This is a good explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined

Comment: But I just want to export a variable data doesnot have to do anything with document in node.js. Also what is the solution of that problem how could I get data from my index.js to node.js.

Comment: The document you are trying to import is having an Error, so it won't work. The execution will end when the error occurs. Remove the `document` statement and try again.

Comment: As I mentioned in my Question that when I remove document from index.js there is no error and I successfully import the data. But in my app my index.js has multiple document.getElements due to the fact that I have an html file and I have to manipulate certain elements using js. So my concern is to export some data present in a variable to my node.js or new.js file. I already know that document is messing with node but whats the solution.

Comment: @Subhan — You need to redesign your JS structure. Don't mix "code you want to run on Node.js and in browsers" with "code that can only run in browsers". Move the shared code into its own module them import it into both the Node.js and browser specific modules.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with `document.getElementById()` as in Node.js the browser DOM API is not defined.

So the first line of the `index.js` module is failing, and you can't reach the `module.exports` line.

**UPDATE**

To postpone the evaluation of the offending code, one solution can be to wrap the code in a function, that can be exported as well and run just when the file is inside a browser.

here the example:

```js
// index.js
function myGetElementBy(d, selector) {
    let intro = d.getElementById(selector);
}

let name = "Harry";
module.exports = {
 name,
 myGetElementBy,
};

// new.js
let {name, myGetElementBy} = require("./index.js");
console.log(name);

if (window && 'document' in window) {
   myGetElementBy(document, 'intro')
}
```

Now the module is exporting an object that contains the function other than the variable `name`.

Comment: if I move module.exports at the very first line and document at last line the problem still sustains.

Comment: It's not going to fix the issue, as Node.js module evaluate all the file.

Comment: Is there any solution so I can export my data of one js file(containing document.get) to another js file?

Comment: you have not got my point. Query not resolved yet.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer in a way that is more clear.