# Jsoup like library for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, jsoup

Is there any API for Node.js to get and query html from URLs and static html?

I like to do something like this to use with webscrape:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

I have a look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977945/html-parser-on-node-js) and looked most of those APIs, but I haven't found (perhaps I couldn't identify) anything so similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Jsdom` is probably what you want https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom
You can use it in combination with jquery to query the dom. Here's an example on how I've been using it on one of my projects https://github.com/gabesoft/seryth/blob/master/lib/sanitizer.js
You'll probably also need `request` to get the html from urls https://github.com/request/request