# get and replace img src value from html data

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have html file and it stored in AWS S3. I already read that html content file with NodeJS AWS-SDK function(getObject) and it works very well then give me a data. The question is, how to get "src" url from that html data? and how to replace it with new url?

this my example code, I run it in cmd windows :

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {Bucket: 'myStoreName/content', Key: 'index.html'};

s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  }
  else {
    var html = data.Body.toString();
    console.log(html);
  }    
});
```

The result from code above is :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>This is sample of test</p>
        <img src="./myimage.jpg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

All I want just replce src url to be src="cid:unique@kreata.ee". Is there anyone know how to solve it? is there other way? thankyou for any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977945/html-parser-on-node-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use some parser for this.

[Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) is my choice.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {Bucket: 'myStoreName/content', Key: 'index.html'};

s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  }
  else {
    var $ = cheerio.load( data.Body.toString() );
    $('body').find('img').attr('src', 'SRC_VALUE_TO_SET');
        console.log( $.html() );
  }    
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanksss! it works. But one question again, how if I have more <img>? and it must have different src.

Comment: If you've more img elements you will have to use a parent element to select them separately if you've access to the HTML you pass. 

FYI: Cheerio have selectors similar to jQuery.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I have figure out and I use each(function(index, element)) to loop all img.