# How to parse a JavaScript object from a HTML page I crawl?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, web-crawler, html-parsing

I'm trying to index a food recipes page, and the actual recipe is stored as an object within a JavaScript in the page.

One example URL: http://www.dagbladet.no/mat/oppskrift/bakt-potet-med-romme-og-blamuggostdressing

If I open the developer tool in the browser and type:

```
console.dir(food.recipeItem.title)
```

I get the title back:

```
"Bakt potet med rømme- og blåmuggostdressing"
```

All nice and dandy, and just what I need. But how can I get ahold of that script and parse it within a Node.js application? Cheerio will maybe help me find the script, but not do much more than that? Or maybe it will? I'm not sure how to do it, and not what is the most computation-effective answer. Or most solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy, all you have to do is **parse** the returned HTML.
If you inspect the returned HTML (view-source:http://www.dagbladet.no/mat/oppskrift/bakt-potet-med-romme-og-blamuggostdressing), you will find a script tag which contains all information  you need in several **javascript** **variables**. These variables holds **JSON** data. Since the script is hardcoded directly into the HTML document, and not obtained by XHR or similar, parsing the HTML is the only way of doing this.

So basically you have these 3 steps:

**1.** send HTTP GET request to [the link above](https://oppskrift.dagbladet.no/oppskrift/bakt-potet-med-romme-og-blamuggostdressing)

**2.** parse the HTML string to extract the **script** tag by using some library (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977945/html-parser-on-node-js) link to decide which library to use).

**3.**  parse the javascript string (extracted script from step 2) to extract JSON data. Check [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)
 library for Node.js

Comment: Thanks @Borna ! Step 2 is the part I'm struggling with. I'll handle finding the script tag with cheerio, but do I then need to parse the content of the script? And how to do that?

Comment: Hi, I made some changes, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!