# HTML parser for node typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, html-parsing

I am creating a `node.js` application written in `Typescript`. Its one of the functionality is to parse HTML file. But I can't seem to find the HTML parser written in `Typescript`.

As, normal npm modules specified in [HTML-parser on Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977945/html-parser-on-node-js) are not importing in my application.

I have tried installing the node.js module like

```
npm install domhandler
```

and, then imported the module in my `main.ts` file like

```
import * as parser from "htmlparser2"
```

It was throwing error

> Cannot find module 'htmlparser2'

Is there any way I can import these normal npm modules in my `Typescript` node application?
Or, is there any typescript module which I can use to parse HTML file?

Comment: Why are they not importing?

Comment: Please provide code so that we will know what you have done and how to correct if something is wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question with what I have tried.

Comment: If you are using version `2.x` of typescript then you simply need to `npm install @types/domhandler` to install the definition files for this module, otherwise you'll need to use [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings).