# javascript replace tag-regex undepend html-attributes

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying whole the time to replace such strings:

```
<title id="hello">my title </title>
<title >my title </title>
<title id="hello" class="blue">my title </title>
```

i need regex, which replace text between title-tags, undepend attributes.
sadly i get only second example with this regex:

```
str.replace(/<\/?title>/g,'')
```

Has anybody ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to avoid using regex for parsing HTML.

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

---

Instead, generate a temporary DOM element with the content and applying all the change finally get the HTML content.

```js
var html = `<title id="hello">my title </title>
<title >my title </title>
<title id="hello" class="blue">my title </title>`;

// generate a temporary div elementt
var temp = document.createElement('div');
// set its html content as the string
temp.innerHTML = html;

//do the rest here
// get all title tags
Array.from(temp.getElementsByTagName('title'))
  // iterate over the title tag and do the necessary chenges
  .forEach(function(ele) {
    ele.innerHTML = 'new content'
  })

// get back the updated html content from dom element
console.log(temp.innerHTML);
```

---

Fore NodeJS refer : [HTML-parser on Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977945/html-parser-on-node-js)

Comment: Thats nice solution, but in my context it´s does not help me.
I investigate web-sites for title-tag. 
I get a body from any web-page and look for title-tag.
Some web-pages have within title-tag attributes and some pages not.
I dont have "document"-Object. I am working with NodeJs.