# Shared NodeJS and browser libraries? DOMParser => dom-parser and createNodeIterator => dom-node-iterator

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, domparser

Now that I've realized that executing a function like

```
let parser = new DOMParser();
```

works only when it's executed with a browser, but not with a server like Express/Node, then, **what are the options?**

I've read many posts with NodeJS alternatives to DOMParser, but then there're the libraries

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-parser

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-node-iterator

Are these ones valid alternatives? Do I install them and adapt the method calls depending on whether it is the browser or Node the one that uses them?

I'm asking because looking at posts like this one [HTML-parser on Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977945/html-parser-on-node-js) it doesn't seem so simple