# How to replace HTML link with text link?

Tags: javascript

i want to replace html links in a string with text links, for example:

`<a href="test.com">` should become `test.com`.

I cant figure out any regex matching all my patterns. Cause links might have more attributes in different orders:

```html
<a class="test" href="test.com" title="test">
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Maybe post some code and show us what you've tried to solve the problem

Comment: Don't use a regexp, parse the string into a DOM fragment and use DOM methods.

Comment: RegExp can't parse HTML, use document.links collection to find links. But a llink needs HTML, plain text is ... well ... plain text, clicking on it doesn't trigger navigation.

Comment: What about the link text? An HTML link should be in the form `<a ...>text</a>`.

Comment: Why do the other attributes cause a problem? You can just skip over everything else with `[^>]*`.

Comment: share the full string

Comment: But to others point. Use the DOM here.

Comment: i dont want to parse HTML.. i want to replace <a tags.. regex should be able to do that...
i dont use it in dom, its a nodejs application. i get html strings (no complete html file)

Comment: You didn't find all that important enough information to include it to the question?

Comment: @fredalex  : what about closing tag ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977945/html-parser-on-node-js/7978072#7978072 Use a parser, all the regexps will go to haywire if you'll get some encoded strings.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = '<a class="test" href="test.com" title="test">'
let result = str.split(/href="/)[1].split('"')[0]
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary DOM element with the string as HTML content and iterate over all `a` tags and replace it with the corresponding link(by getting `href` attribute).

```js
let html = `<a class="test" href="test.com" title="test">`;

// create a temporary div element
let tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
// set html content as your string
tempDiv.innerHTML = html;

// get all a tags and iterate
tempDiv.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(ele => {
  // replace element with corresponding link
  ele.replaceWith(ele.getAttribute('href')) // or ele.href
})

// get html content of temporary element
console.log(tempDiv.innerHTML)
```

---

Or alternately you can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) for parsing html content.

```js
let html = `<a class="test" href="test.com" title="test">`;

// parser
let parser = new DOMParser();
// parse the string which returs a document object
doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");


// get all a tags and iterate
doc.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(ele => {
  // replace element with corresponding link
  ele.replaceWith(ele.getAttribute('href')) // or ele.href
})

// get html content from body
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML)
```

---

**UPDATE :** With regex you can extract and replace the `a` tag in the following method(not prefered).

```js
var str = '<a class="test" href="test.com" title="test">';

console.log(str.replace(/<a[^>]*href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>(?:.*?<\/a>)?/g, '$1'));


var str1 = '<a class="test" href="test.com" title="test">abc</a>';

console.log(str1.replace(/<a[^>]*href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>(?:.*?<\/a>)?/g, '$1'));
```

Reference : [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)