# Parse HTML string to JS in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I was wondering if there was a better way to capture a value inside an input tag rather than using regex in JS.

```
"<html><head></head><body onload=\"document.form1.submit()\"><form name=\"form1\" method=\"post\" action=\"\" ><input name=\"Token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"\"><input name=\"ID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"12120012732dafd4\"></form></body></html>"
```

Ideally I would like to capture just the ID value `12120012732dafd4`

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no DOM in node you have to initialize a cheerio instance from an HTML string. (this example comes from the cheerio readme)

```
 var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
        $ = cheerio.load("<html><head></head><body onload=\"document.form1.submit()\"><form name=\"form1\" method=\"post\" action=\"\" ><input name=\"Token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"\"><input name=\"ID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"12120012732dafd4\"></form></body></html>"
);
    
    $('input').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio):

```
h = "[your HTML]"
const $ = cheerio.load(h)
console.log("Value:", $("form input[name='ID']").attr("value"))
```

Demo: https://runkit.com/adelriosantiago/get-attr-from-html-in-node

Alternatively you can use [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) or [htmlparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [**JSDom**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) like this:

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const htmlString = /*html*/`<html><head></head><body onload="document.form1.submit()"><form name="form1" method="post" action="" ><input name="Token" type="hidden" value=""><input name="ID" type="hidden" value="12120012732dafd4"></form></body></html>`

const dom = new JSDOM(htmlString);
const value = dom.window.document.querySelector("input[name='ID']").value 

console.log(value); // "12120012732dafd4"
```

[**Demo in RunKit**](https://runkit.com/kylemit/jsdom-demo)

#### Further Reading:

- [HTML-parser on Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7977945/1366033)
- [How do I parse a HTML page with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7372972/1366033)