# Is there a way to grab the first html element that has a certain name (name="name") in Node.JS?

Tags: html, node.js

I'm attempting to grab the first html element that has a certain name, the html looks a little like this: <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value"
How would I grab this element purely from it's name, and since there's a chance multiple elements could have that same name, specifically the first one. (I have the html stored in a string, I am not using puppeteer)

Comment: What is the relationship between the HTML and Node.js? Node.js isn't a browser, it doesn't have an automatic `document` object.

Comment: The language I'm using is Node.JS, and I have the HTML in a string. @Quentin

Comment: It would probably be simpler if you weren't saving these to a string. Could you edit in what your string looks like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301504/parse-html-string-to-js-in-nodejs