# Example of Persistent Connections without polling, and without plugins

Tags: javascript, streaming, comet

I found [an interesting library that allows DOM manipulation from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014561/463304), this allows much of the logic to be hidden from the browser, so all the browser gets to see is what happens when you check the box, it does not actually know what to do when you check the box.

Seeing that [it responds so quickly](http://todos-nquery.nodejitsu.com/), I took a look at the network activity, and found an item with HTTP 101 (switching protocols) and it says the connection is still open.

It seems there is a way in JavaScript to receive **streaming data**.

How can this be? The code is somewhat large and the googling I did indicated it would be called Comet, but there is much more information about the highly cross-browser "long polling", but that does not seem to be what is happening.

What is a (simple) example for how to achieve fast results like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP/1.1 101 response header is the Websocket protocol handshake.

I have found [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to be the best ready rolled library (both client and server), especially when working with JavaScript. Socket.io will drop to flash sockets if possible then last resort long polling in older browsers that do not support Websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Long Polling is a push technology. Before web sockets(HTML 5), the web suffered from class client server problem. The server can not push until client requests. So it was not possible to push data to clients. Long Polling is one of the way to do it.

It works in the simple way. The client would make a request to server, the server if has anything new to server would serve immediately or would wait till new content comes. When ever a new content comes, the server would send the response. On receiving the response, the client would again re-issue a request to the server. There are other ways of implementing Push Technology. Read this : [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)