# Unable to install jquery with node.js - Unable to load Contextify

Tags: jquery, node.js, jsdom

**Update - see bottom of post**

I'm trying to setup jquery in node.js and having some trouble. As [described on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js?answertab=votes#tab-top) I'm installing jquery with `npm install jquery` and am executing my javascript as a script from the command line, rather than running it as a server.

A few points to note:

- OS X 10.7.3
- node.js version 0.6.11
- npm version 1.1.1
- node-waf version 1.5.16

So, from the directory that contains my node script, I `npm install jquery`. Terminal then goes off for 5 seconds and does a few things, particularly, download the modules and build contextify. At the end, the message is `'build' finished successfully`.

Also, from the install log I see:

- htmlparser 1.7.4
- jsdom 0.2.10

I try to run my script at this point: `./script.js`, but this is output:

```
Internal Contextify ERROR: Make sure Contextify is build with your current Node version. 
To rebuild, go to the Contextify root folder and run 'node-waf distclean && node-waf configure build'.
```

So, I do the following:

```
$ cd node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/
$ node-waf distclean && node-waf configure build

'distclean' finished successfully (0.002s)
Setting srcdir to:     /proj/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify 
Setting blddir to:     /proj/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build 
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local 
'configure' finished successfully (0.729s)
Waf: Entering directory `/proj/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build'
[1/2] cxx: src/contextify.cc -> build/Release/src/contextify_1.o
[2/2] cxx_link: build/Release/src/contextify_1.o -> build/Release/contextify.node
Waf: Leaving directory `/proj/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build'
'build' finished successfully (3.335s)
```

However, I still get the `Internal Contextify ERROR` when I run my script. Below is the full error message:

```
Internal Contextify ERROR: Make sure Contextify is built with your current Node version.
To rebuild, go to the Contextify root folder and run 'node-waf distclean && node-waf configure build'.

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: Unable to load shared library /proj/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build/Release/contextify.node
    at Object..node (module.js:472:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>(/proj/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
```

It does seem strange to me that `not found` is the output of `Checking for node path` when compiling, but I don't know what to make of it other than that it is unexpected to me.

If anyone can offer any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it!

**Update - 2/21/12**

After some more research, I have been able to fix the oddity of node path not being found. After executing: `export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node"` in terminal, node path is found during the build process. However, after removing the jquery module and installing/building again, I am still in the same situation.

The contextify.node file exists in the specified release directory, but it still cannot be loaded by my script.

Comment: In the mean time, you can manually create the file by the time someone answers this and explains why its happening.

Comment: Thanks, Shawn. I'd be OK with that, but I'm not sure what file that would be (I'm pretty new to node.js). There is a contextify.node file that gets build in its release directory. Could explain a little more or point me to a reference?

Comment: Im pretty new too, but when I was using jquery, I just added a new js file and linked to it from one of the pages. Im using express framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this appears to be an issue with 32-bit vs 64-bit and is specifically related to node.js v0.6.11 at this pont. Apparently Contextify is a 64-bit library, but the download of node.js 0.6.11 was a 32-bit executable. Downgrading to v0.6.10 appears to work for me.

Not sure what this means for the future, but here are the resources I found for anyone else interested:

- https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/19
- http://www.websector.de/blog/2011/12/15/quick-tip-node-how-to-downgrade-node-js-on-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the contextify problem by following these instructions:

"For those who are used to the magic of npm, to use the pre-built binary from Benvie just download the ZIP file at https://github.com/Benvie/contextify/zipball/master , extract it into your node_modules folder, and then rename the folder to "contextify". Note that this binary only works in windows with node 0.6, so be careful if you're sharing your node_modules folder via source control with non-windows users.
(edit: fixed the link as pointed out in the next comment)"

from https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/12