# node-gyp configure error at execvp()

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

Under Node 0.8.20

Compile the node addon from [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/test/addons/hello-world)

Have node-gyp, python 2.7.3 and gcc installed. When running

```
node-gyp configure
```

errors occurred. Below is the error outputs:

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@0.8.5
gyp info using node@0.8.20 | linux | arm
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: execvp(): Permission denied
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:540:15)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:638:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.ChildProcess.spawn.stdin (child_process.js:815:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:358:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.6.11-7-ARCH+
gyp ERR! command "node" "/root/opt/node/bin/node-gyp" "configure"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/hello
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.20
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.8.5
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I have python installed at /root/opt/python/bin/python and node installed at /root/opt/node/bin/node. But I have set path to PATH env.

I couldn't find what wrong is.

Comment: works if path to python is added to environmental variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to set npm python paramter:

```
npm config set python /usr/bin/python2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I would like set the path of python to `PYTHON_PATH` instead of `PYTHON`. But I have made a mistake that I set the path of python to the environment variable `PYTHON`. If the `PYTHON` has been set, `node-gyp` whould consider it as python exective and never look for python from the `PATH`s.

So when `node-gyp` ran python script, it passed the path of a directory to the first parameter of execvp syscalls. Therefore, it got the permission denied error.