# how to include jquery library to a pure javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

script to create a node server(node_server.js) , i want to include jquery library to that file.

i want to use jquery in this file ,  how to include jquery library to this javascript file ,

note that , i am not including this file to a view , this is a node server written in javascript .

part of my server

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request,response)
{
    var pathRegex = new RegExp('^/publish/?$');
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    if (pathRegex.test(pathname)) {
       publish(request, response);
    } else {
       render404(request, response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeking a new maintainer, but you might give [node-jquery](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery) a try. See also the SO thread ["Can I use jQuery with node.js?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js)