# How can I load an html file without issuing an http request using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ant, rhino

I will try to summarize the best I can what I need and what is blocking me to do it.

**What I need**

I need to append script tags to the head of an html file, BUT during my "build" process. I'm using ant as a automation build tool, and I would like to avoid placing tokens in my HTML file to then replace it with ant, or also I will like to avoid any midway solution using regular expression matching. Waht I would really like to use is plain javascript running through rhino javascript interpreter and exceute it easily from an ant task, and finally add the script tag dinamically.

**What is blocking me?**

I really don't know anyway that I can load an html file without issuing a GET or a POST HTTP methods. Cause I'm building my code from source I don't have it under an HTTP server, so I wish I could find someway to load the HTML DOM into a javascript variable and then write it with the new script tag that I need.

**I need all the DOM manipulation features without having a browser that renders the HTML file.**

Best!
Demian

Comment: You you give an example (in code or some sort of pseudocode) of exactly what you're trying to do? It's not  clear from the question.

Comment: Try this http://api.jquery.com/load/, I only read your question's title though.

Comment: I'm sorry @MichaelMior, I'm just thinking how could I approach a solution. I don't have any code yet :(. But in order to clarify more, I have one html file and a javascript file (supose under the same path). What I will like to do is some sort of $.load(foo.html) to build the DOM object but I don't have foo.html under an http server. I would like to load it using only the file path (not an XHR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you would like to have a valid DOM object from an HTML file, as if you were running in a browser, but do it "offline"? e.g. be able to do a jQuery selector on the DOM and edit it?

- You can always start by looking into an embeded open source browser (http://www.chromium.org/)?
- But I would look into node.js, see this question [Can I use jQuery with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js)

This will allow you to do DOM traversing and modifications without a browser as far as I understand

Comment: Hi Eran, thanks a lot for your answer :). Yes, you understood me well, I need to have all the DOM manipulation features without a browser that renders my html file upfront. I will research how could I dot it from node. Thanks!