# 32bit or 64 bit does it matter to jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, 32bit-64bit

Does it matter to jQuery/javascript if the website server platform is 32 bit or 64 bit? I have some code written, which is currently running on 32 bit linux. will there be problem running this javascript (jQuery) code from a website hosted on 64 bit server?

Comment: Javascript isn't run on the server. It is run on the client (the person viewing the page).

Comment: @Shmiddty: You are incorrect. Read about [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/).

Comment: Can you run jQuery on Node.js?

Comment: jQuery uses objects (`document`, `window`, etc.) and what not that are provided only in a browser environment.  It is not relevant to server-side execution within Node.js.

Comment: @S.Albano, Brad: Yes, you can of course use jQuery in NodeJS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js - jQuery is just a JavaScript framework, it is not magic. NodeJS understands JavaScript, so it also is able to understand jQuery.

Comment: @Tadeck, I never stated jQuery was magic, or was not JavaScript.  I am simply pointing out that it **is not relevant** on the server.  Sure, there are some cases where it may be useful server-side, as pointed out in the question you link to, but this is not a typical use case, in my experience..

Comment: I was just unaware that NodeJS had packages that added in the missing browser globals. That is neat, but not important for this question.

Comment: @rajeev, Are you using NodeJS or some other form of javascript that runs on the server?

Comment: @S.Albano: It is very relevant to the comment stating "_Javascript isn't run on the server._". It is also an answer to other comment: "_Can you run jQuery on Node.js?_" (yours). All I want is to clearly inform newbies that **both JavaScript and jQuery (JS framework) can be run on the server**.

Comment: And I would have upvoted the original version of your previous comment for that reason. The misunderstanding arose in your first comment, with any reference to jquery hidden behind a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CPU doesn't matter, JavaScript is a high-level interpreted programming language, it doesn't really care about the architecture at all, as long as the engine it runs on works correctly.

In your case it sounds like clientside JavaScript, which runs on the client (normally), and that's basically the users computer and not your server.

Comment: As a note, it shouldn't matter if the client is running 32 bit or 64 bit as well

Answer (score 5):

No, it makes no difference at all.  Your JavaScript isn't ran on any CPU directly.  CPU architecture only matters for compiled code.