# concatenate 2 files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 HTML Files.

these 2 HTML files will make be needed to added.

Is there a way in Javascript, Jquery that I can add 2 files and get a single file.

In Jquery I saw append  and other functions but my usecase is I want to add 2 Big files

Comment: javascript is a front end language, sounds like you want to generate a file, which you'll need to do in a server side language such as php.

Comment: What do you want to do with the concatenated file, where do you need it? Do you want to store it, or do you want to use it in further processing?

Comment: You can't handle files with js, without specific addons or plugins in your browser, whatever you are trying to do is better to achieve it from the back end if possible

Comment: you can make an ajax call to each file and load them into one place in page. Would require 2 ajax calls

Comment: @Christian: JavaScript can also be a backend-language, and with Node.js you will be able to read two files and print one.

Comment: Bergi Thank you . I am looking to use this in express(node)..I am looking how I can add 2 files in expressnode and also how I can add some variables/text to that exsisting htmlpage in node. How to do that?

Comment: Haha, I didn't actually think this was referring to node. Incorrect tags.

Comment: I don't think he knows what he wants ...

Comment: I did not mention node in the actual question because I want to know from java script perceptive..for me node is almost like java script..

Comment: node _is_ javascript, but there's a big difference between front-end and back-end javascript. And jQuery is for front end use, and you're not going to be able to generate a file that way.

Comment: SpYk3HH- please dont come to conclusion :-) I know what I am asking

Comment: Actually [you can use jQuery with node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js), learning something every day!

Comment: ok Thank you. so if I use javascript as backend how do I make it

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the exact code but you shouldn't need it (jQuery well documented)

1. Use Ajax to get the HTML data (the code)
2. Presumably you want to add the content? You'll need to get the data between the body tag (and possibly between the head tag too)
3. Concatenate those. Remember, the ajax data is a string

Although, this type of thing sounds better for a server side language like PHP. You can make an ajax request for the "builder" PHP file, which will return the two files put together. Plus, if you use templates right, you won't need to do the head/body filtering messy stuff

Example pseudocode

```
//template.php
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php include 'foo.php'; ?>
    </body>
</html>

//foo.php
My html content
<h1>Hello</h1>

//bar.php
My other page
<h1>About</h1>

//builder.php
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php include 'foo.php'; include 'bar.php'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not the best example (very, very simple) but it should give you the idea. Get an ajax request on builder.php, and that's all your content. You could make it even more powerful by creating a builder.php file that takes filename parameters to concatenate (and you should do validation on these files...)